# How to write an IF else statement without 'else' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I can't use `else` in my script; how can I implement an `if else` statement without using `else`?

I'm trying to resize a div:

```
function hideTable(){
    var table = document.getElementById('PDemo');
    if(table.style.width == "50%") table.style.width = "150px";
    if(table.style.width == "150px") table.style.width = "50%";
}
```

This script doesn't work because as soon as the first `if` statement is executed, the condition for the second `if` statement becomes true, so that executes too, and thus nothing changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can't use an `else` (and that is *crazy*), use a `switch`.

```
switch (table.style.width) {

    case '50%':
       ...
       break;

    case '150px':
       ...
       break;

}
```

Answer (score 21):

The ternary operator:

```
condition ? execTrue() : execFalse();
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if (condition) {
    execTrue();
}
else {
    execFalse();
}
```

You *can* write an if/else in 1 line, just don't press enter...

```
if (condition) { execTrue(); } else { execFalse(); }
```

Further, you can write any statement of arbitrary complexity on one line:

```
if(condition1) { exec1(); } else if(condition2) { exec2(); } else { execFalse() }
```

If you're having the issue where the second if statement executes as well, you want to impose mutual exclusion, i.e., using `else if` instead of just `if` on each subsequent conditional.

Comment: haha. it's a reporting software. its not an alternitive for eclipse or anything. it does'nt seem to like those elses. thanks anyway

Comment: hmm, so you're typing these commands into like a one-line console or something? I see. Well if it doesn't "like" the else, the ternary operator is your solution.

Answer (score 11):

Save the value into a different variable.

```
function hideTable(){
  var table = document.getElementById('PDemo');
  var width = table.style.width;
  if(width == "50%") table.style.width = "150px";
  if(width == "150px") table.style.width = "50%";
}
```

Comment: But shouldn't it change `table.style.width` at the end? Otherwise, that function does not seem to be doing much at all.

Comment: It won't because it's checking the stored value in the variable which won't change. Your original code was checking the actual attribute value in both conditions, and that would change if the first condition was met.

Answer (score 7):

```
if(/*condition a*/){/*statements a*/}else if(/*condition b*/){/*statements b*/}else{/*statements c/*}
```

One line only.

Answer (score 0):

With a *while* loop for the sake of uniqueness.

```
while (!resized){
  if(width == "50%") {table.style.width = "150px";resized=true;break};
  if(width == "150px") table.style.width = "50%";resized=true;break};
  resized=true;
}
```

Comment: I prefer the `do {//Stuff} while (0);` idiom better.

Answer (score 0):

The && operator is called a short-circuit operator. It will return the value of the second operand based on the value of the first operand.

For example: (explanation : If 'profile' permission exists in permArray then load the user's profile)

```
isPermitted(permArray, 'profile') && loadProfile();
```

The && operator is useful also for checking for null objects before accessing their attributes. For example...

```
var name = person && person.getName();
```

Comment: Yes, but how does that answer the question?