# How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

What is the `?:` (question mark and colon operator aka. conditional or "ternary") operator and how can I use it?

Comment: Fun fact: some languages (namely [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/)) actually have an operand `?:` (as you've written it, with no statement between) - the [Elvis operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-ElvisOperator%28%3F%3A%29). Pretty clever.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript if alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688337/javascript-if-alternative)

Answer (score 765, accepted):

This is a one-line shorthand for an if-else statement. It's called the conditional operator.<sup>1</sup>

Here is an example of code that could be shortened with the conditional operator:

```
var userType;
if (userIsYoungerThan18) {
  userType = "Minor";
} else {
  userType = "Adult";
}

if (userIsYoungerThan21) {
  serveDrink("Grape Juice");
} else {
  serveDrink("Wine");
}
```

This can be shortened with the `?:` like so:

```
var userType = userIsYoungerThan18 ? "Minor" : "Adult";

serveDrink(userIsYoungerThan21 ? "Grape Juice" : "Wine");
```

Like all expressions, the conditional operator can also be used as a standalone statement with side-effects, though this is [unusual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069278/omitting-the-second-expression-when-using-the-if-else-shorthand/11069295#11069295) outside of minification:

```
userIsYoungerThan21 ? serveGrapeJuice() : serveWine();
```

They can even be chained:

```
serveDrink(userIsYoungerThan4 ? 'Milk' : userIsYoungerThan21 ? 'Grape Juice' : 'Wine');
```

Be careful, though, or you will end up with convoluted code like this:

```
var k = a ? (b ? (c ? d : e) : (d ? e : f)) : f ? (g ? h : i) : j;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *Often called "the ternary operator," but in fact it's just **a** ternary operator [an operator accepting three operands]. It's the only one JavaScript currently has, though.*

Comment: Just to clarify the name: `ternary` is the *type* of operator (i.e. it has 3 parts). The name of *that specific ternary operator* is the `conditional operator`. There just happens to only be one ternary operator in JS so the terms get misused.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight ternary form is technically an expression, and expressions can contain other expressions to form expression trees.  that code right there is what an expression tree looks like :) see: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/expressions-vs-statements/

Comment: Strongly recommend updating the example for the common use case, not a side-effect use case frequently cited as an abusage of the operator.

Comment: Not sure why there is a little grammar blurb at the bottom, but it is incorrect. If javascript only has 1 of a type of operator, then it is definitely correct to say THE ternary operator and not A ternary operator... Saying "this ternary operator is A ternary operator in javascript (and it is the only one)" is silly, just use THE and it implies all of that.

Comment: So I was optimising some PHP and I came across a blog post that showed a ternary being used to assign a value as such, `$somevar = $value['val'] ?: 'N/a'` Which uses the evaluator as the value for true. Does anyone know if we can do the like in JS? which would essentially be like; `someJSVar = data.node ?: 'N/A'`

Comment: @MarkCarpenterJr In JavaScript the typical way to do that is with the `||` operator, since it short-circuits if the value on the left is truthy.

Comment: @PeterOlson So `someJSVar = data.node || 'N/A'` ? Edit-- I see it in the answer below... That's pretty sweet!

Answer (score 178):

I want to *add* some to the given answers.

In case you encounter (or want to use) a ternary in a situation like 'display a variable if it's set, else...', you can make it even shorter, *without a ternary*.

---

Instead of:

```
var welcomeMessage  = 'Hello ' + (username ? username : 'guest');
```

You can use:

```
var welcomeMessage  = 'Hello ' + (username || 'guest');
```

*This is Javascripts equivallent of PHP's shorthand ternary operator `?:`*

Or even:

```
var welcomeMessage  = 'Hello ' + (username || something || maybethis || 'guest');
```

It evaluates the variable, and if it's false or unset, it goes on to the next.

Comment: I was struggling with ternary and eventually found this answer. Thank you!

Comment: If I were not to use the braces around the ternary operator in  `'Hello ' + (username ? username : 'guest')`, `Hello + ` if ignored and just the outcome of ternary operation is returned. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: @Shiva Without the brackes, it evalutes the *whole* left part: `'Hello ' + username`, which is always `true`, because it's a string with a length greater than 0.

Answer (score 29):

It's called the 'ternary' or 'conditional' operator.

**Example**

> The ?: operator can be used as a
>   shortcut for an if...else statement.
>   It is typically used as part of a
>   larger expression where an if...else
>   statement would be awkward. For
>   example:

```
var now = new Date();
var greeting = "Good" + ((now.getHours() > 17) ? " evening." : " day.");
```

> The example creates a string
>   containing "Good evening." if it is
>   after 6pm. The equivalent code using
>   an if...else statement would look as
>   follows:

```
var now = new Date();
var greeting = "Good";
if (now.getHours() > 17)
   greeting += " evening.";
else
   greeting += " day.";
```

From [MSDN JS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Basically it's a shorthand conditional statement.

Also see:

- [Operator precedence with Javascript Ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788917/javascript-ternary-operator)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?:)

Comment: It's actually called the conditional operator.

Comment: @Michael - That's because it is **a** ternary operator but that isn't it's formal name. Conceivably a future version of JavaScript could introduce a new ternary operator.

Comment: Its a ternary conditional operator

Comment: @ChaosPandion link to a reference or it didn't happen.

Comment: @Michael - Please see section **11.12  Conditional Operator ( ? : )** of the specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

Answer (score 26):

It's a little hard to google when all you have are symbols ;) The terms to use are "JavaScript conditional operator".

If you see any more funny symbols in JavaScript, you should try looking up JavaScript's operators first: [Mozilla Developer Center's list of operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference#Operators). The one exception you're likely to encounter is the [`$` symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856156/what-does-js-mean).

To answer your question, **conditional operators** replace simple if statements. An example is best:

```
var insurancePremium = age > 21 ? 100 : 200;
```

Instead of:

```
var insurancePremium;

if (age > 21) {
    insurancePremium = 100;
} else {
    insurancePremium = 200;
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Most of the answers are correct but I want to add little more. The **ternary operator** is right-associative, which means it can be **chained** in the following way `if … else-if … else-if … else` :

```
function example() {
    return condition1 ? value1
         : condition2 ? value2
         : condition3 ? value3
         : value4;
}
```

Equivalent to:

```
function example() {
    if (condition1) { return value1; }
    else if (condition2) { return value2; }
    else if (condition3) { return value3; }
    else { return value4; }
}
```

More details is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: I landed here while wondering if there's any compatibility issue in using the chained format which could lead to any side-effect as it used to be for nested ternary operators. It seems to be fully supported since its born, don't know if you have any additional info.

Answer (score 9):

```
z = (x == y ? 1 : 2);
```

is equivalent to

```
if (x == y)
    z = 1;
else
    z = 2;
```

except, of course, it's shorter.

Answer (score 5):

**Ternary Operator**

Commonly we have conditional statements in Javascript.

*Example:*

```
if (true) {
    console.log(1)
} 
else {
    console.log(0)
}
# Answer
# 1
```

but it contain two or more lines and cannot assign to a variable.
Javascript have a solution for this Problem **Ternary Operator**.
Ternary Operator can write in one line and assign to a variable.

*Example:*

```
var operator = true ? 1 : 0
console.log(operator)
# Answer
# 1
```

This Ternary operator is Similar in C programming language.

Answer (score 4):

It is called the ternary operator

```
tmp = (foo==1 ? true : false);
```

Comment: It is called the conditional operator. It happens to be the sole example of _a_ ternary operator in the language.

Comment: tmp = foo == 1    does the same thing so it would be enough

Answer (score 4):

Hey mate just remember js works by evaluating to either true or false, right?

let's take a ternary operator :

```
questionAnswered ? "Awesome!" : "damn" ;
```

First, js checks whether questionAnswered is `true` or `false`.

if  `true` ( `?` ) you will get "Awesome!"

else ( `:` ) you will get "damn";

Hope this helps friend :)

Answer (score 3):

Ternary expressions are very useful in JS, especially React. Here's a simplified answer to the many good, detailed ones provided.

```
condition ? expressionIfTrue : expressionIfFalse
```

Think of `expressionIfTrue` as the OG if statement rendering true;
think of `expressionIfFalse` as the else statement.

Example:

```
var x = 1;
(x == 1) ? y=x : y=z;
```

this checked the value of x, the first y=(value) returned if true, the second return after the colon : returned y=(value) if false.

Comment: this should be `y = (x == 1) ? x : z`

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 9
y = 8
```

unary

```
++x
--x
```

Binary

```
z = x + y
```

Ternary

```
2>3 ? true : false;
2<3 ? true : false;
2<3 ? "2 is lesser than 3" : "2 is greater than 3";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an `if statement` all on one line.

So

```
var x=1;
(x == 1) ? y="true" : y="false";
alert(y);
```

The expression to be evaluated is in the `( )`

If it matches true, execute the code after the `?`

If it matches false, execute the code after the `:`

Comment: var x=1;  
y = (x == 1) ? true : false;

Answer (score 1):

> The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator
>   that takes three operands. This operator is frequently used as a
>   shortcut for the if statement.

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

> If condition is true, the operator returns the value of expr1;
>   otherwise, it returns the value of expr2.

```
function fact(n) {
  if (n > 1) {
    return n * fact(n-1);
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
  // we can replace the above code in a single line of code as below
  //return (n != 1) ? n * fact(n - 1) : 1;
}
console.log(fact(5));
```

For more clarification please read [MDN document link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 1):

We can use with Jquery as well as length as below example :

Suppose we have GuarantorName textbox which has value and want to get firstname and lastname- it may be null.
So rathar than

```
        var gnamesplit = $("#txtGuarantorName").val().split(" ");
        var gLastName = "";
        var gFirstName = "";
        if(gnamesplit.length > 0 ){
           gLastName  = gnamesplit[0];        
        }
        if(gnamesplit.length > 1 ){
           gFirstName = gnamesplit[1];        
        }
```

We can use below code with Jquery with minimum code

```js
    

    var gnamesplit = $("#txtGuarantorName").val().split(" ");
    var gLastName = gnamesplit.length > 0  ? gnamesplit[0] : "";
    var gFirstName =  gnamesplit.length > 1  ? gnamesplit[1] : "";
    $("#txtLastName").val(gLastName);
    $("#txtFirstName").val(gFirstName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div >
  Guarantor Name: <input type="text" id="txtGuarantorName" value="ASP.NET Core"  /><br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  
  First Name: <input type="text" id="txtLastName" value="ASP.NET Core"  />
  Last Name: <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" value="ASP.NET Core"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using Ternary operator, write a program to Print “Even Number”, if the number is even or Print “Odd Number”, if the number is odd.

```js
let a = 13;
let b = a%2!==0 ? "is Odd number" : "is Even number";
// let b = a%2==0 ? "is Even number" : "is Odd number";
console.log(a+" "+b);
```

Output : 13 is Odd number

Answer (score 0):

It's called the `ternary operator`. For some more info, here's another question I answered regarding this:

[How to write an IF else statement without 'else'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392255/how-to-write-an-if-else-statement-without-else/5392271#5392271)

Comment: Actually ternary is the *type* of operator (i.e. it has 3 parts). The name of *that specific ternary operator* is the `conditional operator`. There just happens to only be one ternary operator in JS so the terms get misused.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not exactly the most elegant way to do this. But for someone who is not familiar with ternary operators, this could prove useful. My personal preference is to do 1-liner fallbacks instead of condition-blocks.

```
  // var firstName = 'John'; // Undefined
  var lastName = 'Doe';

  // if lastName or firstName is undefined, false, null or empty => fallback to empty string
  lastName = lastName || '';
  firstName = firstName || '';

  var displayName = '';

  // if lastName (or firstName) is undefined, false, null or empty
  // displayName equals 'John' OR 'Doe'

  // if lastName and firstName are not empty
  // a space is inserted between the names
  displayName = (!lastName || !firstName) ? firstName + lastName : firstName + ' ' + lastName;


  // if display name is undefined, false, null or empty => fallback to 'Unnamed'
  displayName = displayName || 'Unnamed';

  console.log(displayName);
```

[Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 0):

If you have one condition check instance function in **javascript**. it's easy to use **ternary operator**. which will only need **one single line** to implement.
Ex:

```
    private module : string ='';
    private page:boolean = false;
    async mounted(){
     if(this.module=== 'Main')
    {
    this.page = true;}
    else{
    this.page = false;
    }
}
```

a function like this with one condition can be written as follow.

```
this.page = this.module=== 'Main' ?true:false;
```

**condition ? if True : if False**

Comment: it would be clearer to just return `this.page = this.module=== 'Main'`. it's already a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator is just a simple way to write if else condition. It is widely used in ReactJS.

For Example:

```js
const x = 'foo';

// Instead of if else use this
x === 'foo' ? alert('True') : alert('False');

// Output
// alert box will prompt 'True'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

```
 (sunday == 'True') ? sun="<span class='label label-success'>S</span>" : sun="<span class='label label-danger'>S</span>";

 sun = "<span class='label " + ((sunday === 'True' ? 'label-success' : 'label-danger') + "'>S</span>"
```

Comment: you can append html also with ternary operator

Comment: thats really not how you should write ternary assignment and also use === not == other wise you might as well just do `sunday ?`.it should be `sun = "<span class='label " + ((sunday === 'True' ? 'label-success' : 'label-danger') + "'>S</span>"`

Comment: the whole point of the conditional ternary is to shorten conditional assignment values otherwise you should just use an if statement

Comment: now tell me this one is correct or not . if you say wrong then still this is working and i am using my project..

Comment: I know it "works" how you have it in the first example, but so does what I've provided that you put as the second version.  Notice how much unnecessary duplication there is in the top version vs the one I gave you. JS is code that gets sent to the browser, so code length matters

Comment: also if you do sunday == 'True', then if sunday is actually equal to 'False', it conditional is still gonna evaluate to `true`  `'True' == 'False'` is `true` but `'True' === 'False'` is false

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley No, that is wrong. `"True"` is never equal to `"False"`, no matter if you use abstract or strict equality comparison.