# Java: Ternary with no return. (For method calling)

Tags: java, methods, boolean, return, ternary

I was wondering if it was possible to do a ternary operation but without returning anything.

If it's not possible in Java is it possible in other languages, if so which ones apply?

```
name.isChecked() ? name.setChecked(true):name.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: It's possible in JavaScript, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6260001/320399

Answer (score 65, accepted):

No, you can't.  But what's the point of this over an `if-else` statement?  Are you really trying to save 7 characters?

```
if (name.isChecked()) {
    name.setChecked(true);
} else {
    name.setChecked(false);
}
```

or if you prefer bad style:

```
if (name.isChecked()) name.setChecked(true); else name.setChecked(false);
```

Never mind the fact that you can just do (in this case):

```
name.setChecked(name.isChecked());
```

The point of the ternary or "conditional" operator is to introduce conditionals into an *expression*.  In other words, this:

```
int max = a > b ? a : b;
```

is meant to be shorthand for this:

```
int max;
if ( a > b ) {
    max = a;
} else {
    max = b;
}
```

If there is no value being produced, the conditional operator is not a shortcut.

Comment: Using Stream.forEach lambda there are cases where in my opinion writing (item -> item.isA() ? doA() : doB()) would be far more elegant than expanding with curly brackets and if/else.

Comment: What is the argument for not being able to? Just makes sense for cleaner code in some cases.

Comment: @html_programmer: Of course other arguments could be made, but my personal opinion is that delineating control structures with side effects and conditional expressions leads to cleaner code.  IMO burying a side effect in an expression hides the most important part of the code, both here and with the related `someConditionTrue && doSideEffect()` that you sometimes see.  But as with much code style, it's highly subjective.

Answer (score 17):

> I was wondering if it was possible to do a ternary operation but without returning anything.

No it is not possible:

1. The 2nd and 3rd operands are required to be non-void expressions; i.e. they must produce some actual value.

   > *"It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method."* - [JLS 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).
2. A ternary expression is an expression, and cannot be used as a statement.

   > *"Certain kinds of expressions may be used as statements by following them with semicolons."* ... and the ternary expression is not one of those kinds - [JLS 14.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8).

If you really, really want to use a ternary expression but not use the value of the expression, then the simplest thing is to assign the value to a dummy variable, and add an annotation to suppress the warning about the variable not being used.

But a better idea is to use a plain `if` statement.

> If it's not possible in Java is it possible in other languages, if so which ones apply?

I'm a bit rusty, but I believe that C, C++ and Perl all allow arbitrary expressions to be used in places where their values are not used.

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes, you can use ternary operation on method arguments to solve your request.

```
name.setChecked(name.isChecked() ? true : false);
```

By the way, the best solution for your problem is

```
name.setChecked(name.isChecked());
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the use case in the question is just a poor example because it's equivalent to the following statement:

```
name.setChecked(name.isChecked());
```

... which doesn't make sense either. But the intent is clear and there are indeed many relevant use cases.

The only viable and general solution is adding a helper method like this:

```
static void ternaryVoid(boolean condition, Runnable ifTrue, Runnable ifFalse) {
    (condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse).run();
}
```

and using it like this:

```
ternaryVoid(name.isChecked(), () -> name.setChecked(true), () -> name.setChecked(false));
```

But it loses the elegance of ternary operator and worth the 'effort' only if used by multiple parts of the code and only if nanoseconds don't matter.

> *But what's the point of this over an if-else statement? Are you really trying to save 7 characters?*

I'm surprised that such statements appear in a form of rhetorical questions. Yes, saving 4 lines and making the code more elegant is important, especially in the context of functional programming.

Moreover, it's at least arguable whether `void` methods return a complete `Void`. Essentially, they return a notification of a completed task. This is why logically, ternary expression makes sense equally regardless of whether it returns something or nothing:

```
condition ? doThis() : doThat();
```

Here is a real world example of a class which may process millions of incremental updates per second:

```
public class DataHandler {

    private final TreeMap<Integer, Long> tree = new TreeMap<>();

    public void onUpdate(int price, long amount) {
        if (amount == 0) {
            tree.remove(price);
        } else {
            tree.put(price, amount);
        }
    }
}
```

If allowed, the `onUpdate()` method would be a nice ternary expression like this:

```
public void onUpdate(int price, long amount) {
    (amount == 0) ? tree.remove(price) : tree.put(price, amount); // compilation error
}
```

Fortunately, in some cases like this, **both target methods return values, and these values are of the same type**, which is `Long` in this case. This allows either to make the `onUpdate` method to return the previous `amount` at `price` (which is even useful)

```
public Long onUpdate(int price, long amount) {
    return (amount == 0) ? tree.remove(price) : tree.put(price, amount);
}
```

... or alternatively (e.g. in case the method is determined by an interface), to use a dummy variable and suppress its uselessness warning:

```
public void onUpdate(int price, long amount) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Long dummy = (amount == 0) ? tree.remove(price) : tree.put(price, amount);
}
```

Otherwise, these solutions are not applicable, and as answered by others, doesn't exist. For instance, one may try the following:

```
Consumer<Void> dummy = (x) -> {};
dummy.accept(/*...*/);
```

but interestingly, the second line compiles with neither anything nor nothing as an argument.

It seems the best general solution is the above helper method `ternaryVoid()`.

Answer (score 0):

In java following code isn't possible:

```
(your-condition) ? (true-statements) : (false-statements)
```

for sample you can't compile following snipet code :

```
(1==1) ? System.out.println("") : System.out.println("");
```

you achieve following compilation error:

```
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
```

Comment: `(your-condition) ? (true-statements) : (false-statements)` is possible in java but it has to return a value (it cannot be void) and you have to assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return some value and it will not work if you want it to act like a void method which performs some action without a returning a value.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This question is already answered. Please, [read the FAQ to learn how to ask questions properly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

No, but in C++ you can write a ternary that can return void(), more useful in the empty if than the else, when turning the condition inside out for an single-line if makes it too long (and in expressions, instead of lambda).

However they have limitations and I don't recommend nesting in either single line statement (especially with bodies in non-ternary)) unless it's a clean looking hack like else if.

Regarding your sample, ternary operators aren't useful when returning the condition directly, even if it's the opposite, you can put an ! before the condition without ternary.