# How to use the ternary operator in Java without an else branch

Tags: java

I have this expresion and I want to have it in a sigle line using the `?` operator.

```
for (Area a : listaArea) {
    if (a.getIdArea() == user.getIdArea()) {
        user.setNomArea(a.getNomArea());
    }
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
for (Area a : listaArea) {a.getIdArea() == user.getIdArea() ? user.setNomArea(a.getNomArea())}
```

How to convert that `if` into a `?` expresion?

Comment: Really not a good duplicate from this question.

Comment: As a side note: I wouldn't use the ternary operator in your case, because it's less readable.

Comment: Assuming the set.. is void, you canno't do it.

Comment: @user2336315 so it is just impossible?

Comment: @KazMiller Yes, as the JLS states : _"It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method."_. Also why would you want to use the ternary operator for this kind of thing?

Comment: You can not use the ternary operator in void context. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450864/java-ternary-with-no-return-for-method-calling)

Comment: @Jens "If there is no value being produced, the conditional operator is not a shortcut" that should be the answer

Comment: @Kayaman No you can't if the setters have a return type as void.

Comment: Reopen reviewers - this was closed as a duplicate of the wrong question as noted by @Jens - please vote to reopen if only so we can then vote to close again with the correct duplicate

Comment: @RobV how to Reopen reviewers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the JLS states:

> It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand
>   expression to be an invocation of a void method.

Assuming that your setter is more likely to have no return type, then no it's not possible to use the ternary operator in this context.