# Lambda expresions and "? :" operator in Java 14

Tags: java, lambda, operators

Good day to everyone,

I have a question regarding the usage of the `? :` operator in the lambda expressions, especially in the switch statements. Could you kindly clarify, why the below code would not work and will be marked as `Not a statement`

```
 switch (separatedTransaction[0]) {
            case "u" -> processUpdate(Integer.parseInt(separatedTransaction[1]), Integer.parseInt(separatedTransaction[2]), separatedTransaction[3]);
            case "o" -> processOrder(separatedTransaction[1], Integer.parseInt(separatedTransaction[2]));
            case "q" -> separatedTransaction.length > 2 ? processQuery(Integer.parseInt(separatedTransaction[2])):processQuery(separatedTransaction[1]);
            default -> System.out.println("Invalid transaction");
        }
```

And the next one will.

```
 switch (separatedTransaction[0]) {
            case "u" -> processUpdate(Integer.parseInt(separatedTransaction[1]), Integer.parseInt(separatedTransaction[2]), separatedTransaction[3]);
            case "o" -> processOrder(separatedTransaction[1], Integer.parseInt(separatedTransaction[2]));
            case "q" -> {
                if (separatedTransaction.length > 2) {
                    processQuery(Integer.parseInt(separatedTransaction[2]));
                } else {
                    processQuery(separatedTransaction[1]);
                }
            }
            default -> System.out.println("Invalid transaction");
        }
```

Is there a way to use the `? :` operator in the lambda expressions at all?
If so, could you kindly provide some code examples.

Comment: `processQuery()` must have a non void return type in order to be used as the 2nd or 3rd operands of the ternary conditional expression.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450864/java-ternary-with-no-return-for-method-calling

Comment: BTW, there are no lambda expressions in the code you posted.

Comment: Use `if-else` if you are calling `void` methods on operands.

Comment: Thanks guys for the clarification, this was the answer I've searched for. Non-void return methods should be used in the ternary expressions.

Comment: The ternary operator returns a value, which doesn't work with that switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about all the jazz of that switch statement, it's a red herring; completely irrelevant to the situation (and as a side note, those `->` arrows aren't 'lambdas'. They're just part of switch-as-expression syntax).

Just this:

`separatedTransaction.length > 2 ? processQuery(Integer.parseInt(separatedTransaction[2])):processQuery(separatedTransaction[1])`

explains the failure. That is invalid java code. And wrapping it in a new feature introduced in java14 isn't going to make it any more legal.

The ternary operator construct takes the following form:

`booleanExpression ? expr1 : expr2`

where `expr1` and `expr2` must themselves be expressions. The type of the whole thing is the common ground between the type of expr1 and expr2, and, crucially, that common ground must not be `void`.

That's the problem: `processQuery` returns `void` and therefore cannot be used in any of the 3 'slots' in a ternary expression.