# Is there way to use ternary expression with a continue statement inside a loop in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use a *ternary expression* along with a *continue or break construct* inside a *do-while loop* in *Dart* but I get a compilation error.

```
do
{
  expr ? print('Conditionally print something') : continue;

}while(expr == true);
```

The above code fails at compile-time but if I use a pair of *if-else* decision structure, **the code works**. So, the question to the community is why the ternary expression is not working along with *continue or break* construct?

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator takes 3 expressions in the form of `(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3).`

You can't execute statements in ternary operator, nor only in dart but in other languages also. Since break and continue are not expressions but statements they cant be used here

Comment: Thank you for your kind response, would you care to elaborate why this is so?

Comment: The ternary conditional operator is an operator that combines multiple expressions into a larger expression. An expression must evaluate to something. A statement performs an action. Expressions can be used as statements, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: I tried wrapping the continue statement in an anonymous function but still it failed as well, that also boggled my mind?

Comment: that is because you can't use control structure statements  like break , continue outside loops

Comment: The statement was inside a loop; the else part of the ternary expression, but I understand now, thank you for your elaborate explanations 

Comment: what I meant was when you wrap continue in function , that function has no access to loop , no matter even if you keep that function in loop , for eg try keeping the function in for loop , can you access the counter variable without function arguments , no . This works similarly .

Answer (score 1):

- No, you can't do it.
- continue is a Dart Statement (read below), and print is a function

**First**

- In the Dart Language Specification section 17.23 explains how it works.
  https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf
- Search the original document, because **the copy/paste doesn't seems to work well**.

**17.23 Conditional conditional**

A conditional expression evaluates one of two expressions based on a boolean
condition.

{conditionalExpression} ::= {ifNullExpression}
(‘?’ {expressionWithoutCascade} ‘:’ {expressionWithoutCascade})?
Evaluation of a conditional expression c of the form e1?e2 : e3 proceeds as

follows:
First, e1 is evaluated to an object o1. It is a dynamic error if the runtime type of o1 is not bool. If r is true, then the value of c is the result of
evaluating the expression e2. Otherwise the value of c is the result of evaluating
the expression e3.

**Second**

As you can see the ternary operator requires expressions, but continue, in the same PDF of language specification is defined as an statement, a reserved word, as:

**18 Statements statements**

A statement is a fragment of Dart code that can be executed at run time.
**Statements, unlike expressions, do not evaluate to an object,** but are instead
executed for their effect on the program state and control flow

**Third**

in the case of print, it's taken as a function I guess, didn't find the specification. Perhaps it returns void.
We can still ask ourselves, why can't we put continue in a function, even in a lambda like () => { continue; } or similar. The short answer is that as said in the specification for the continue statement, if it's not inside a while, etc. is gonna give a compile error. And if it's inside a function, it will prevent that function to reach the return statement, and again, the ternary will expect a return value.

We can still research a little more, many things are inside the specification.

- When something like this happens, you can also search without specifying the language, to get information on JAVA or C# that may help you.
- [Java: Ternary with no return. (For method calling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450864/java-ternary-with-no-return-for-method-calling)
- It seems that Swift language would allow continue and break inside the ternary, as per this article - https://forums.swift.org/t/bringing-control-flow-keywords-to-the-ternary-operator/13878

Answer (score 0):

Because a `ternary operator` is returning a value. With the following syntax:

```
condition ? expresion1 : expression2
```

which means:

If condition is true, it `return` expression1. If it is not it `return` expression2.

So, you can't use statement like this:

```
print('Conditionally print something')
```

or

```
continue
```

[An expression evaluates to a value. A statement does something.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4728162/4758255)

Comment: You can use `print ("Anything " )` in  ternary operator

Comment: Try running this 

`void main() {
  var a = 1;
  (a==1) ? print("abc"): print('xyz');
}`

Comment: `print('Anything')` can be used with a ternary operator. `void main() { true ? print('hi') : print('bye');` is perfectly valid. `print('Anything')` is still an *expression*, but the *result* of that expression is of type `void`, and that means that the result cannot be *used*.

Comment: void main() {   var a = 1;   (a==1) ? print("abc"): print('xyz'); } this would work without issues, I just wanted to understand why I can't alter the loop execution with continue statement using a ternary expression. The focus being on why, not how to use ternary expression. Thank you very much on your kind contributions 