# How to enable and disable a submit button based on if passwords are matching?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am creating a form where the user will register for a website and in that form there are two input fields to help confirm the users password. I am trying to disable the submit button when the passwords are not matching and then reenable it when the passwords do match. I currently have the disable part working but I cannot reenable it.

I have tried looking at this post [how to check confirm password field in form without reloading page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727317/how-to-check-confirm-password-field-in-form-without-reloading-page) but I couldn't figure out what I needed to do beyond what I currently have.

**Code:**

```html
<form id="myform" action="process_registration.php" class="basic-grey" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="firstName" id="firstName">* First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" minlength=1 required />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="lastName" id="lastName">* Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" minlength=1 required />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="email" id="email">* Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" minlength=1 required />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="username" id="usernameLabel">* Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" minlength=1 required />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="password" id="passwordLabel">* Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" minlength=1 required />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="passwordConfirm" id="passwordLabelConfirm">* Password Confirmation:</label>
    <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" minlength=1 required />
    <span id="message"></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>

</form>

<?php include ABSOLUTE_PATH . '_includes/footer.inc.php'; ?>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('form').validate();
</script>

<script>
  $('#password, #passwordConfirm').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($('#password').val() == $('#passwordConfirm').val()) {
      $('#message').html('Matching').css('color', 'green');
      $('submit').prop('disabled', false);
    } else
      $('#message').html('Not Matching').css('color', 'red');
    $('submit').prop('disabled', true);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work for two reasons:

1. Because you're using `$('submit')` instead of `$('#submit')`. You're mistakenly using `submit` as though it were the `tagname` rather than the `id` of the button.
2. Because, the `else` part of your `if` statement, where the code to re-enable the button is located has no braces `{}` and thus only executes the first instruction. The second one is considered to be outside the `if` statement and it's executed *always* last, thus keeping the button permanently disabled.

**Snippet:**

<sub>*(only kept the code essential for demonstration)*</sub>

```js
/* --- JavaScript --- */
$('form').validate();

$('#password, #passwordConfirm').on('keyup', function() {
  if ($('#password').val() == $('#passwordConfirm').val()) {
    $('#message').html('Matching').css('color', 'green');
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#message').html('Not Matching').css('color', 'red');
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<!--- HTML --->
<form id="myform" action="process_registration.php" class="basic-grey" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="password" id="passwordLabel">* Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" minlength=1 required />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="passwordConfirm" id="passwordLabelConfirm">*
      Password Confirmation:</label>
    <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm"
      minlength=1 required />
    <span id="message"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>

<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js'>
</script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js">
</script>
```

---

**Note:** *In the answer of the question you linked the code works, because there is only one instruction following `else`, whereas you have two.*

Comment: Thank you for this solution! Unfortunately, after pressing refresh the script doesn't see the differences in the form fields and I can submit the form even if fields don't match. Is there a way to retain "Not matching" status after reload, if the fields don't match?

Comment: You can simply re-run the event handler during the `load` event of the document.

Comment: This is something I won't know how to do, but will at least know in which direction to look now.

Answer (score 0):

I found out actually that it doesn't always work.  Therefor I added a return false to the script.

```
$('#user_password, #user_password_retype').on('keyup', function () {
  if ($('#user_password').val() == $('#user_password_retype').val()) {
     $('#message').html('Matching').css('color', 'green');
     $("#savebutton").prop('disabled', false);
     return true;
  } else 
     $('#message').html('Not Matching').css('color', 'red');
     $("#savebutton").prop('disabled',true);
     return false;
  });
```