# Javascript sign up function

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

Here, I am trying to use the `signUp()` function to get the users details and store them into the database. I already tested the backend Javascript file (signUp function) using postman and it works perfectly fine.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Login</title>

    <link href="css\signup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script>

        function signUp() {
            if (document.getElementById("password2").value == document.getElementById("cfmpassword2").value) {
                var users = new Object();
                users.firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
                users.lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
                users.username2 = document.getElementById("username2").value;
                users.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                users.password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;


                var postUser = new XMLHttpRequest(); // new HttpRequest instance to send user details

                postUser.open("POST", "/users", true); //Use the HTTP POST method to send data to server

                postUser.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

                // Convert the data in "users" object to JSON format before sending to the server.
                postUser.send(JSON.stringify(users));
            }
            else {
                alert("Password column and Confirm Password column doesn't match!")
            }
        }

    </script>


</head>

<body>

    <div style="margin-top: -703px; margin-left: 1250px; position: absolute;">
        <!-- Sign up button -->
        <p>Need an account? &nbsp;
            <button class="signup" id='signup' onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" style="width:auto; height: 6.1vh;">
                Sign Up
            </button>
        </p>
    </div>

    <!-- The Sign Up Modal-->
    <div id="id02" class="modal2">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close2" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

        <!-- Modal Content -->
        <form class="modal-content2">
            <div class="container3">
                <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
                <hr>
                <label for="firstName"><b>First Name</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstName" required>

                <label for="lastName"><b>Last Name</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lastName" required>

                <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="username2" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>

                <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

                <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" id="password2" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

                <label for="psw-confirm"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" id="cfmpassword2" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="psw-confirm" required>

                <br>
                <br>
                <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="aboutus.html" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms &
                        Privacy</a>.</p>

                <div class="clearfix">
                    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn2">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="signupbtn" onclick="signUp()">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

If `Confirm Password` matches `Password`, I will get the user details and send the data to my database server. Else, an alert msg is supposed to pop up.

However, I after trying it out, I see nothing being added into my database. My `else` part works though, an alert message does pop up on my browser.

Is this due to an error about the `Confirm Password`? Because I have a very similar set of working codes except that it doesn't contain the `Confirm Password` column. I got the confirm password from here [how to check confirm password field in form without reloading page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727317/how-to-check-confirm-password-field-in-form-without-reloading-page/21727518)

Could someone please help identify the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the request is sent successfully then the code that processes this data is where the problem lies. Please add the relevant PHP ( or other ) code that does the db work

Comment: You also want to change the button from a submit to a standard button ~ OR call `event.preventDefault` in your function to prevent the page from reloading

Comment: @RamRaider if i change to a standard button, it made the button unclickable

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `signUp()` when a **submit** button is clicked.

The JavaScript runs, but as the XHR request is being prepared, the form is submitted, the browser navigates, and the XHR request is canceled.

Don't use a submit button if you aren't submitting the form.

Comment: If I use button with a `type='button'`, I cannot click the button

Comment: @CBCH — That shouldn't happen under normal circumstances. Maybe you have other JS or CSS interfering with it.

Comment: I don't see anything in my css file that will affect the button type; I added my css file in the question

Comment: Jus like https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_signup_form_modal when i change it to button, it also doesnt work?

Comment: @CBCH – That example doesn't use JavaScript to make a request with XHR. The whole point of it is to submit the form.

Comment: @CBCH — You're the one who wrote `var postUser = new XMLHttpRequest();` and everything that follows it.

Answer (score -1):

Your comment that changing the `submit` to a regular `button` prevents you from actually being able to click it seems a little odd. The below code has a standard button and seems OK which suggests a css issue perhaps. I tested this with a php endpoint and the request was sent OK so it ought to be find hitting your javascript endpoint - unless there is another factor (css most likely ) interfering with the button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="css/signup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script>
        function signUp(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            if (document.getElementById("password2").value == document.getElementById("cfmpassword2").value) {
                var users = new Object();
                    users.firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
                    users.lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
                    users.username2 = document.getElementById("username2").value;
                    users.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                    users.password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;


                var postUser = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    /* 
                        Optional:
                        A callback to process response from the server and possibly manipulate the DOM
                        or let the user know if things went OK.
                    */
                    postUser.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 ){
                            alert( this.response )
                        }
                    }
                    postUser.open( "POST", "/users", true );
                    postUser.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
                    postUser.send( JSON.stringify( users ) );
            }
            else {
                alert("Password column and Confirm Password column doesn't match!")
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="margin-top: -703px; margin-left: 1250px; position: absolute;">
        <!-- Sign up button -->
        <p>Need an account? &nbsp;
            <button class="signup" id='signup' onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" style="width:auto; height: 6.1vh;">
                Sign Up
            </button>
        </p>
    </div>

    <!-- The Sign Up Modal-->
    <div id="id02" class="modal2">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close2" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

        <!-- Modal Content -->
        <form class="modal-content2">
            <div class="container3">
                <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
                <hr>
                <label for="firstName"><b>First Name</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstName" required>

                <label for="lastName"><b>Last Name</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lastName" required>

                <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="username2" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>

                <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

                <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" id="password2" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

                <label for="psw-confirm"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" id="cfmpassword2" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="psw-confirm" required>

                <br>
                <br>

                <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="aboutus.html" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

                <div class="clearfix">
                    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn2">Cancel</button>
                    <!--
                        modify the button to a standard button rather than a submit
                        - this enables the ajax function to do what is intended.

                        An alternative would be to invoke `event.preventDefault()` within
                        the signUp(event) function to stop the submit button from actually
                        submitting the form
                    -->
                    <button type="button" class="signupbtn" onclick="signUp(event)">Sign Up</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I used this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_signup_form.asp to code my signup form (modal), doesnt seem to have anything that will affect the button type.