# how to check confirm password field in form without reloading page or clicking on button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello i need some help i sure this topic have been answer before but i try use some of the reference from [how to check confirm password field in form without reloading page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727317/how-to-check-confirm-password-field-in-form-without-reloading-page/21727518)
I woud like  that the password and confirm password will display the error if password do not match without have to click on submit button or reloading page i have my code below where it don't work, i would like for some help as how i can display it of course i not using just a normal form i am using

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
```

This is my code below

```js
function onChange() {
  const password = document.querySelector('input[name=validationpassword]');
  const confirm = document.querySelector('input[name=validationconfirmpassword]');
  if (confirm.value === password.value) {
    confirm.setCustomValidity('');
  } else {
    confirm.setCustomValidity('Passwords do not match');
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">*Password:</label>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex">
      <input name="validationpassword" onChange="onChange()" type="password" class="form-control pass" id="passwords" placeholder="Password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{7,}$" required>
      <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i>
      <!-- <div style="margin-left: 15px;" class="invalid-tooltip password-empty" >
                                    Enter a password!
                                </div> -->
      <!--<div id="passwordvalidator" class="invalid-tooltip password-notmeet">
      Password must meet the following requirements:
      <br><br>
      <label class="color-text"> At least one capital letter</label>
      <br>
      <label class="color-text"> At least one special character</label>
      <br>
      <label class="color-text"> At least one number</label>
      <br>
      <label class="color-text"> Be at least 7 letter</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> -->

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="validationconfirmpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">*Re-enter<br>&#10;Password:</label>
        <div class="col-6 d-flex">
          <input name="validationconfirmpassword" onChange="onChange()" type="password" class="form-control confirmpass" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
          <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="toggleconfirmPassword"></i>

        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: do u got some kind of code i can  refer to 
looking for some answer to this

Comment: Are you looking like this https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `onkeyup()` event for check conform password.

Here down is example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var password = document.querySelector('input[name=validationpassword]').value;
  var confirm = document.querySelector('input[name=validationconfirmpassword]').value;
  
  var matchedOrNot = (confirm == password) ? "Password matched" : "Password not matched"; 

  var color = (matchedOrNot == "Password matched") ? "green" : "red";

  document.getElementById("toggleconfirmPassword").className = color;

  document.getElementById("toggleconfirmPassword").innerHTML = matchedOrNot;
}
```

```css
.red
{
     margin-top: 5px;
     color: red;
     font-weight: bold;
}
    
.green
{
     margin-top: 5px;
     color: green;
     font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">*Password:</label>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex">
      <input name="validationpassword" type="password" class="form-control pass" id="passwords" placeholder="Password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{7,}$" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationconfirmpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">*Re-enter Password:</label>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex">
      <input name="validationconfirmpassword" onkeyup="myFunction()" type="password" class="form-control confirmpass" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
      <br>
      <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="toggleconfirmPassword"></i>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi i have tested this the color seem to go bug what i mean try a password and reenter password the correct combination then try with a wrong password the color will remain green still any fix ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onkeyup` to check the passwords with every key press.

So instead of onChange even use this:

```
onkeyup ="onChange()"
```

```js
function onChange() {
  const password = document.querySelector('input[name=validationpassword]');
  
  const confirm = document.querySelector('input[name=validationconfirmpassword]');
  console.log(confirm.value === password.value)
  if (confirm.value === password.value) {
    confirm.setCustomValidity('');
  } else {
    confirm.setCustomValidity('Passwords do not match');
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">*Password:</label>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex">
      <input name="validationpassword" onChange="onChange()" type="password" class="form-control pass" id="passwords" placeholder="Password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{7,}$" required>
      <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i>
      <!-- <div style="margin-left: 15px;" class="invalid-tooltip password-empty" >
                                    Enter a password!
                                </div> -->
      <!--<div id="passwordvalidator" class="invalid-tooltip password-notmeet">
      Password must meet the following requirements:
      <br><br>
      <label class="color-text"> At least one capital letter</label>
      <br>
      <label class="color-text"> At least one special character</label>
      <br>
      <label class="color-text"> At least one number</label>
      <br>
      <label class="color-text"> Be at least 7 letter</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> -->

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="validationconfirmpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">*Re-enter<br>&#10;Password:</label>
        <div class="col-6 d-flex">
          <input name="validationconfirmpassword" onkeyup ="onChange()" type="password" class="form-control confirmpass" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
          <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="toggleconfirmPassword"></i>

        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is generally [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) to use inline event handlers (`<div onclick="...">`.

Here is a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It uses a handler for the `keyup` and `focusin` events comparing both values and messages the user about the result. The handling is set for both password fields.

```js
$(`#confirm_password, #passwords`).on({
  keyup: handleConfirmation,
  focusin: handleConfirmation} );

function handleConfirmation() {
  const pass = $(`#passwords`).val();
  const compare = $(`#confirm_password`).val();
  
  // one of the fields is empty, remove message
  if (!pass.trim() || !compare.trim()) {
     return $(`#toggleconfirmPassword`).html(``)
  }
  
  // otherwise, compare and display result
  const isOk = pass === compare;
  $(`#toggleconfirmPassword`).html(isOk ? ` OK ` : `Passwords are not equal (yet)`);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
}

#toggleconfirmPassword {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="validationpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">
  *Password:
</label>
<input name="validationpassword" type="password" id="passwords"
    placeholder="Password" required>
<div>
  <label for="validationconfirmpassword">
    *Re-enter password:
  </label>
  <input name="validationconfirmpassword" type="password" 
    id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
  <i id="toggleconfirmPassword"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer i just want to ask if the user remove the input for both it display the ok would it be possible if input = '' the display dont show the ok or password not match ?

Comment: Sure, see the edited answer ;)