# Came across weird javascript operation

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project, designed by someone else. I came across the following operation. I have no idea what it is doing. It seems to be returning 1.

Anyone care to elaborate?
Thank you!

```
   ( 7  > 8?2:1)
```

Comment: This is [a quite frequently asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/js-how-to-use-the-ternary-operator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a).

It consists of `(condition) ? (expression1) : (expression2)`. The entire expression will evaluate to `(expression1)` if `(condition)` is true, and `(expression2)` if `(condition)` is false.

```
var i = (7 > 8 ? 2 : 1);
```

translates into

```
if (7 > 8)
{
  i = 2;
}
else
{
  i = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a)

Your example would return 2 if 7 > 8, or 1 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`? :` is a ternary operator.  This is equivalent to

```
var x = 0;
if (7 > 8){
  x = 2;
} else {
  x = 1;
}
```

It is a terse way of expressing simple conditional statements.  It is a great way to conditionally assign values to a variable without the verbose semantics used above.