# What is the use of ? and :

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JS How to use the ?: (ternary) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/js-how-to-use-the-ternary-operator)

I download one plugin for wordpress in that plugin there is one javascript.
Into that js code I don't understand how it works.

```
function ddet_javascript() {

echo '
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!-- 
function expand(param) { 
param.style.display=(param.style.display=="none") ? "" : "none"; 
 } 
  //--></script>';
}
```

In this code I don't understand the line given below.

`param.style.display=(param.style.display=="none") ? "" : "none";`

what is the use of ? and : in this line. please let me know if anyone know about it.

Comment: jQuery != JavaScript. There is no jQuery in this post. At all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an operator:

> (condition) ? true : false

It is like:

```
if(param.style.display=="none")
       param.style.display="";
else
       param.style.display="none;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is ternary operator.
it's works like if else statement.

view this link:

http://davidwalsh.name/learning-ternary-operators-tips-tricks

http://jqfundamentals.com/#example-2.16

Comment: This link is really helpful for me to understand the ternary operator.

Answer (score 2):

It's the ternary conditional operator: The expression

```
Cond ? a : b
```

evaluates `Cond` and lazily returns `a` if it was true, and otherwise returns `b`.

The entire result of the expression in your case is assigned to `param.style.display`. In other words, if `display` is already set to `"none"`, it will be set to `""`, and otherwise it will be set to `"none"`.

This operator is common in many languages, since it provides you with a single *expression* whose value is conditional on something.

Comment: I really want JavaScript to include a second ternary operator so everyone gets confused. (Just kidding, I only sort of want it)

Answer (score 2):

In your code it works like this:

```
if(param.style.display=="none"){
   param.style.display = "";  
} else{
    param.style.display = "none";  
}
```

Comment: is that clear to you @Wasim Kazi

Comment: ya Sandinp Now I'm clear that how we can use ternary operator in Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

It is called conditional (ternary) operator.

```
test ? expression1 : expression2
```

If test is true, it returns the expression 1 else returns expression 2.

And this is not specific to jquery but a javascript operator.

For more info, [ternary operator javascript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 for getting the name right (ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.4). :-)

Answer (score 0):

x=a?b:c, ?: is a ternary operator (works on 3 operands).
It means if a is true then x=b else x=c

Answer (score 0):

```
if (param.style.display=="none")
  param.style.display = "";
else
  param.style.display = "none";
```