# using javascript variable conditionally in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

in the following code i have written a condition 
`(if (epsflag==0)<?php $a=",hide:'true'";?> )`.i want to implement the same condition using javascript.what i mean is that i want to condiionally use a javascript variable in my JSON.any help will be appreciated.if my question is not clear please let me know.

{display: 'Wave Name', name : 'wavename',  sortable : true, align: 'left'`<?php echo "$a"?>}`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function rowdata(epsflag,respflag){
if (epsflag==0) {
<?php $a=",hide:'true'";?>
}else
{
<?php $a=",hide:'false'";?> 
}                           
//alert(respflag);
$("#flex1").flexigrid(
{

url: myurl, 
dataType: 'json',
colModel : [
{display: 'Nr.', name : 'nr',  sortable : true, align: 'center',width:25},
{display: 'Datum', name : 'consultationdate',  sortable : true, align: 'left'},
{display: 'Wave Name', name : 'wavename',  sortable : true, align: 'left'<?php echo "$a"?>},
{display: 'Name', name : 'respname',  sortable : true, align: 'left'},
{display: 'E-mail', name : 'email',  sortable : true, align: 'left',width:180},
{display: 'Telefoon', name : 'telefoon',  sortable : true, align: 'left'},
{display: 'Medewerker', name : 'consultationwith',  sortable : true, align: 'left'}
                                    ],  

                            });
                        }
```

Comment: Have an example (pseudo-syntax) of how to use this "javascript variable"?

Comment: i tried a lot of stuff but not working.if u can give me an example that will  be good.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is desired, hence why I asked for some "pseudo syntax" of the desired behavior. If you can show what is *meant* by "condiionally use a javascript variable", then perhaps I can provide some insight! (Or at least edit the title/question so that someone else can :)

Comment: its mentioned in my question in the beginning itself.have a look again.

Comment: That looks like PHP. Show me what the desired hypothetical syntax in *JavaScript* looks like.

Comment: if (epsflag==0) {
var a=",hide:'true'";
}else
{
var b=",hide:'false'"; 
}

Comment: The answer is likely: ["use ?:"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/js-how-to-use-the-ternary-operator), but be aware that, *from within* JavaScript Object Notation (which is a *superset* of JSON), there is no way to entirely conditionally *exclude* a key if `?:` is used.

Comment: can u please elaborate with an example code.

Comment: I've added a link to the previous comment. Anyway: `x = someValue(); y = { foo: "foo", bar: x ? "x is not falsey" : undefined }` (note that this is *not* valid JSON, but is valid JavaScript and the key `bar` is *assigned in both cases*). To truly add a key conditionally, it can only be done *after* the object is created (from the JSON/JavaScript Literal Object syntax).

Comment: i guess we cant add the condition inside JSON.so wat i want is to declare the condition in javascript and than use that inside JSON.if it is working with PHP than it should work with javascript also.

Comment: Nope! PHP *generates* output (JSON/JavaScript). However, JSON/JavaScript is limited to certain rules. These rules can be *bypassed* by PHP (as it runs ahead of time and just returns some text which is interpreted as HTML/JSON/whatever) but *cannot* be ignored by JSON or a JavaScript Object Literal. While one *could* generate JSON (which is just technically just text markup) in JavaScript and then pass it to `JSON.parse`, this is would require an intermediate string and parse step. (Remember that embedding "JSON" directly into JavaScript works because JSON is a *subset* of valid JavaScript).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

Comment: @Quentin please read my question carefully,its not duplicate of wat u mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this help:

```
function rowdata(epsflag,respflag){

    $("#flex1").flexigrid(
    {

    url: myurl, 
    dataType: 'json',
    colModel : [
        {display: 'Nr.', name : 'nr',  sortable : true, align: 'center',width:25},
        {display: 'Datum', name : 'consultationdate',  sortable : true, align: 'left'},
        {display: 'Wave Name', name : 'wavename',  sortable : true, align: 'left',hide: (epsflag==0)},
...
```

**UPDATE**

If you want not use variable inside object you may try somthing like this:

```
function rowdata(epsflag,respflag){

    var colModel = {};
    if(epsflag == 0){
        colModel = [
            {display: 'Nr.', name : 'nr',  sortable : true, align: 'center',width:25},
            {display: 'Datum', name : 'consultationdate',  sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Wave Name', name : 'wavename',  sortable : true, align: 'left',hide: true }
            ...
    }else{
        colModel = [
            {display: 'Nr.', name : 'nr',  sortable : true, align: 'center',width:25},
            {display: 'Datum', name : 'consultationdate',  sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Wave Name', name : 'wavename',  sortable : true, align: 'left',hide: false }
            ...
    }

    $("#flex1").flexigrid(
    {

    url: myurl, 
    dataType: 'json',
    colModel : colModel,
    ...
```

Comment: epsflag==0 will always return a boolean value of 0 or 1 not true or false.

Comment: @RishabhRaj are you sure? in this [JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) show that return boolean

Comment: @RishabhRaj in Javascript or PHP?

Comment: actually we have to use the javascript condition in JSON,thats y it is getting bit messy.

Comment: @RishabhRaj in your sample you use not JSON, you use [Object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals)

Comment: upvoting ur answer for ur nice logic :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding how the web works.

PHP is a string processing language. All it does is generate strings. Since the javascript is just a very large string to PHP we can replace it with another test string to get a clearer understanding of what's happening. Lets replace it with `"bla bla bla.."`:

```
bla bla bla bla bla bla
<?php $a=",hide:'true'";?>
bla bla bla bla bla bla
<?php $a=",hide:'false'";?>
bla bla bla bla bla bla
<?php echo "$a"?>
bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

Let's now simplify that:

```
<?php
    $a=",hide:'true'";
    $a=",hide:'false'";
    echo "$a";
?>
```

This is what php executes. Therefore, it outputs the string:

```
bla bla bla bla bla bla    // note: you're not outputting anything here
bla bla bla bla bla bla
,hide:'false'
bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

Now replace the `"bla bla"` with a simplified version of your original string and the output becomes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function rowdata(epsflag,respflag){
    if (epsflag==0) {
                    // note: you echoed nothing here in PHP
    }
    else {
                    // note: you echoed nothing here in PHP
    }

    $("#flex1").flexigrid({
      colModel : [
        {align:'left',hide:'false'}  // logically, it's always false
      ]
    });
}
```

Now, if you've been following my explanation and have suddenly realized that PHP doesn't process javascript at all and the browser doesn't see PHP at all then you'll realize that this is a duplicate question of: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429)

So. Now that we understand how the web works, what to do to solve your problem?

For this very specific problem I notice that you don't need to actually pass anything at all back to PHP. All your're trying to do is change a value in a javascript object. So why use PHP to manipulate the javascript source code when you can just use javascript to change the value directly? Doing it in js:

```
var wavedata = {
    display: 'Wave Name',
    name : 'wavename',
    sortable : true
};

if (epsflag==0) {
    wavedata.hide = 'true';
}
else {
    wavedata.hide = 'false';
}  


$("#flex1").flexigrid({
    colModel : [
        // other data
        wavedata,
        // other data
    ]
});
```

Or if you want to keep the source as close as possible to your current code then do what Grundy suggests, only since you want to set the value to the **string** `"true"` or `"false"` change it to:

```
{/* ... */ align: 'left',hide: epsflag==0 ? 'true' : 'false'}
```

Comment: -wow such a great explanation.but m still little confused.i think if i read this answer again than my confusion will be over.thanks a lot for the answer.