# Add multiples to args array

Tags: php, arrays, function

**SOLVED**
(Credits will be added in 10 min.)

I have a custom post type script in my functions.php (Wordpress) of which I do not understand its meaning.

```
$query_args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'post_type'      => $is_some_page ? CPT_ONE : CPT_TWO,
'post_status'    => 'publish',
'paged'          => 1
);
```

The script is loading perfect, no problems there.

**Problem:** I would like to add an additional post_type but I don't understand the `:` symbol... What is its meaning? And how to add more?
This doesn't work:

`'post_type' => $is_some_page ? CPT_ONE : CPT_TWO : CPT_THREE,`

**EDIT:** Thanks for having a look and changing the labels for the question.
Many thanks to everybody else for pointing me in the right direction with the operators.

Comment: This is clearly a `php` question, not `javascript`

Comment: It's a ternary operator: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/js-how-to-use-the-ternary-operator

Comment: `$is_some_page ? CPT_ONE : ($is_other_page ? CPT_TWO : CPT_THREE)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking at is the [ternary if](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) operator (a lot of languages have this, including both PHP and Javascript).

So this:

```
$someVar = $someBool ? $val1 : $ val2
```

is equivalent to:

```
if ($someBool)
{
    $someVar = $val1;
}
else
{
    $someVar = $val2;
}
```

So this:

```
'post_type' => $is_some_page ? CPT_ONE : CPT_TWO : CPT_THREE
```

doesn't make sense because `$is_some_page` can only evaluate as true or false. But it's not clear what your logic should be. Under what situation do you want `post_type` to be `CPT_ONE`, `CPT_TWO` or `CPT_THREE`?

You could do something like this:

```
'post_type' => $is_some_page ? CPT_ONE : ($some_other_condition ? CPT_TWO : CPT_THREE)
```

Which is equivalent to an `if / else if / else`

Comment: Please watch out in your ternary condition. PHP's ternary operator works right-to-left (unless told to otherwise by parenthesises), so it doesn't do what you'd expect: http://codepad.org/o3tgL4Lw

Comment: It can also give [very very odd results](http://codepad.org/gTprxKHX). Eg: `var_dump(true ? 1 : false ? 2 : 3);` prints `int(2)` while `var_dump(true ? 1 : (false ? 2 : 3));` prints `int(1)`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Ugh, PHP. So short version is probably avoid nesting ternary operators in PHP because it's PHP.

Comment: @MattBurland Yeah exactly. Apparently PHP reads it as `var_dump((true ? 1 : false) ? 2 : 3)`.