# Usage of ? and : in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand this implementation of mousewheel.jquery.

```
$('.page').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    event.preventDefault(); // if you want to prevent the window from scrolling

    $(this).animate({left: (delta>0 ? '+' : '-')+'40px'});
});
```

What does `?` and `:` do in:

```
$(this).animate({left: (delta>0 ? '+' : '-')+'40px'});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS How to use the ?: (ternary) operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/js-how-to-use-the-ternary-operator)

Comment: It's the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: jQuery is a wrapper on Javascript. That's just a Javascript inline if-then-else construct. `exp1 ? exp2 : exp3` Means if `exp1` is true, then `exp2` is executed. Otherwise, `exp3` is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

?: is the ternary operator in javascript.

The code

```
$(this).animate({left: (delta>0 ? '+' : '-')+'40px'});
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (delta > 0) {
    $(this).animate({left: '+40px'});
} else {
    $(this).animate({left: '-40px'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the ternary operator. It checks if the bool check preceding the `?` is true. If so, it runs the code before `:` otherwise the code after the `:`.

In this instance, if `delta > 0` returns true, it uses `+`, otherwise it uses `-`.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [ternary operator](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%2C%20ternary%20statement&gws_rd=ssl#q=javascript%2C%20ternary%20operator).  Essentially, the line of code you posted is the same as:

```
if(delta >0) { 
   //output +
} else {
   //output -
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it translates into:

```
if(delta > 0)
   return'+';
else
   return '-';
```

Answer (score 0):

This works like an IF-statement

```
condition ? true : false;


if(delta>0) {
 return "+";
}
else {
 return "-";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ? and : is an alternative way of writing an if-else statement

```
x = y ? z : k
```

is the same as

```
if (y){
 x = z;
}else{
 x = k;
}
```