# How to use if within a map return?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to generate diffrent reactJS code based on datamodel but I get

> In file "~/Scripts/Grid.jsx": Parse Error: Line 13: Unexpected token
>   if (at line 13 column 15) Line: 52 Column:3

With this code

```
var GridRow = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var row;

        row = this.props.cells.map(function(cell, i) {
            return (
                if(cell.URL != null && cell.URL.length > 0){
                    <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>{cell.Text}</td>        
                }
                else {
                    <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>{cell.Text}</td>
                }
            );
        }.bind(this));

        return (
            <tr>
                {row}
            </tr>
        );
    }
});
```

The render part seems to be really limited in how it can be used?

Comment: Have you tried defining each branch and determining which is required _before_ the return statement?

Comment: I'm not quite pro at all with render js, but it seems to me that it doesn't fully rewrite javascript: an if statement may not be found within a return statement

Comment: It appears that in both cases your if-else creates an identical <td />.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You put `return` statement inside `if` clause like so:

```
    row = this.props.cells.map(function(cell, i) {

        if(cell.URL != null && cell.URL.length > 0){
            return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>{cell.Text}</td>;        
        }
        else {
            return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>{cell.Text}</td>;
        }

    }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Can you explain why the if statement cannot write inside the return?

Comment: @Chrisk8er Well, it is not a valid syntax neither in js nor in jsx.

Comment: @Chrisk8er yes it is valid javascript, and is used in JSX all the time. See the answer below on how to user ternary statements

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me - the else statement never seems to fire

Answer (score 11):

You could also use a [ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript) (inline if/else) statement. It might look like this:

```
row = this.props.cells.map(function(cell, i) {
    return (cell.URL != null && cell.URL.length > 0) ? 
        (<td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>{cell.Text}</td>) :
        (<td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>{cell.Text}</td>)
}.bind(this));
```

or es6

```
row = this.props.cells.map((cell, i) => (cell.URL != null && cell.URL.length > 0) ? 
        (<td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>{cell.Text}</td>) :
        (<td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>{cell.Text}</td>)
);
```

but, for readability, I would suggest nilgun's answer.

Although I would remove the else statement, since it is redundant. You could also remove the curly brackets, this is a matter of preference.

```
row = this.props.cells.map(function(cell, i) {
    if(cell.URL != null && cell.URL.length > 0)
        return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>{cell.Text}</td>;        
    return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>{cell.Text}</td>;
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Hi @S.Kiers, on the e6 example, how do we do an else if?

Comment: You are talking about the ternary example? If you need else if, I suggest you use a full if/elseif/else block. Ternary operator is usually just syntactic sugar.

However, if you need to you can 'nest' ternary operators ( example, in react you *could* do this, but don't!):
`condition1 ? 
"This is the IF" : condition2 ?  "This is the ELSE IF" : "This is the ELSE"`