# React : wrap every 3 components into a div

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, components

I am new to React (and JS) and in order to train I am trying to rewrite an old website I've done. On this website I display a list of X products. for very row there are 3 products to display.

I face an issue about styling. I want to use flexbox and thus I have to wrap every 3 products in a div.

This is what I try to do in the render of a component called GiftList :

```
 render() {
    const { list } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="GiftsList">
       {
          list.map((item, index) =>
            {
             
              if(index % 3 === 0){<div>}
              <Product />
              if(index % 3 === 0){</div>}
              
            })   
        }
      
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I also saw this advice : [How to use if within a map return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567549/how-to-use-if-within-a-map-return) but without success. I know I messed up with the '{' and '(' and 'return' ... but I don't get it. Can someone explain me how to do it ?

By the way, is this the best way to achived what I want ? like this :

```
<div>
<Product />
<Product />
<Product />
</div>
<div>
<Product />
<Product />
<Product />
</div>
...
```

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't conditionally render opening/closing tags within array::map in react, each element mapped in JSX needs to be a complete node.

You can achieve the grouping by first splitting your array into an array of chunks, then map both the outer array of chunks ***and*** the inner chunk arrays.

Splitting an array into length-3 chunks there is *this* [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318680/split-array-into-chunks-of-n-length) (closed but points [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273668/how-to-split-a-long-array-into-smaller-arrays-with-javascript)), though this would require some "pre-processing" before rendering.

Given some data array `[0..15]`

```
const data = [...Array(16).keys()];
```

You could copy into a temp array and splice off chunks of 3 elements

```
const data2 = [...data];
const groupedData1 = [];
while(data2.length) {
  groupedData1.push(data2.splice(0, 3));
}
```

```js
const data = [...Array(16).keys()];

const data2 = [...data];
const groupedData1 = [];
while(data2.length) {
  groupedData1.push(data2.splice(0, 3));
}
console.log(groupedData1);
```

If you prefer the more functional, in-line approach commonly used in JSX. Here an array::reduce is used to reduce the data array into chunks of 3, and the final array::filter is used to clear out any ending empty array (as is the case when the chunk length divides the data length.

```
const groupedData2 = data
  .reduce((groups, curr) => {
    const arr = groups[groups.length - 1];
    arr.push(curr);
    if (arr.length === 3) groups.push([]);
    return groups;
  }, [[]])
  .filter((chunk) => chunk.length);
```

```js
const data = [...Array(16).keys()];

const groupedData2 = data
  .reduce((groups, curr) => {
    const arr = groups[groups.length - 1];
    arr.push(curr);
    if (arr.length === 3) groups.push([]);
    return groups;
  }, [[]])
  .filter((chunk) => chunk.length);

console.log(groupedData2);
```

Now to render the chunked arrays

```
data.<inlineChunkProcess>.map((group, i) => (
  <div key={i}>
    {group.map((product, i) => (
      <Product key={i} value={product} />
    ))}
  </div>
))
```

This is a high-level overview, in actuality you'll not want to use the array index as a react key. When chunking/grouping your data you'll want to generate a unique id for *that* group and you'll want each product to have its own unique id (which hopefully is already the case). This will help if/when you need to add or remove any single product from your list.

Example:

```
const Group = () => ({
  id: uuidv4(),
  data: []
});

...

{list
  .reduce(
    (groups, curr) => {
      const group = groups[groups.length - 1];
      group.data.push(curr);
      if (group.data.length === 3) {
        groups.push(new Group());
      }
      return groups;
    },
    [new Group()]
  )
  .filter(({ data }) => data.length)
  .map(({ data, id }, i) => (
    <div key={id} className="myDiv">
      Group Id: {id}
      <div>
        {data.map(({ id, value }, i) => (
          <Product key={id} value={value} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
```

[image: Edit react-wrap-every-3-components-into-a-div]

Comment: Wow !! thank you so much that's exactly what I wanted to know. I'll work on it and try to implement it that way.

Thanks for all the efforts and time you put to answer me !!

Answer (score -1):

The way you currently have it, this will wrap every third `<Product />` in both opening and closing `<div>`s.  You want to return an opening `<div>` tag when the remainder is 0 and a closing `</div>` when the remainder is 2.

```
list.map((item, index) => (
  {index % 3 === 0 ? <div> : ''}
  <Product />
  {index % 3 === 2} ? </div> : ''}
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction indeed !!

The issue is that even with your code I have a Parsing error. When i put the if inside the map everything goes wrong. Same for your answer...  I don't get why