# What means '?' in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain me this line of code and why we use the '?' in javascript?

```
return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
```

Comment: Expression followed immediately by `?` will get executed if condition becomes true else expression after `:` will get executed.. To know more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/js-how-to-use-the-ternary-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a **ternary operator** which also present in other programming languages:

```
return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
       ^^        ^^                     ^^
 if condition     if true               if false(else)
```

The above statement is equivalent to below:

```
if(n>0) {
   return ninja.yell(n-1) + "a";
} else {
   return "hiy";
}
```

For more [read this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The question mark is actually called **[Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)**, usually in programming laguages it is used for a **one line if statement** and it has the following construct:

> condition ? return if condition is **True** : return if condition is **False**

Think the ternary operator as "**then**" and the "**:**" as **else**. So your code will be:

```
return if( n > 0) then ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" else "hiy";
```

Hope you get it now!