# Translating ternary statement to expanded syntax

Tags: javascript

I have this code `F.onmousewheel = function (e) {zoomFactor = e.wheelDelta > 0 ? 10 : 11;}`

Here it is, the smaller version. But I must (and Im learning) use the bigger version, that looks like this:

```
F.onmousewheel = function (e) {

};
```

My qestion is: how looks `{zoomFactor = e.wheelDelta > 0 ? 10 : 11;}` in the bigger version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zoomFactor = e.wheelDelta > 0 ? 10 : 11;` is an expression, so you can simply use that line:

```
F.onmousewheel = function (e) {
  zoomFactor = e.wheelDelta > 0 ? 10 : 11;
};
```

However, if you wish to break apart the ternary expression (the `?` and `:` parts), you could do the following:

```
F.onmousewheel = function (e) {
  if (e.wheelData > 0) {
    zoomFactor = 10;
  } else {
    zoomFactor = 11;
  }
};
```

The ternary expression is essentially saying `if e.wheelDelta is greater than 0, return 10, otherwise return 11`. The `zoomFactor` variable then gets assigned that returned value. To break this out into an `if/else` statement, you just have to understand the ternary syntax.

The `?` denotes the end of the boolean expression, which is `e.wheelDelta > 0`. So we use that as our boolean expression for the `if` statement.

The `:` separates the two options, the first being the value if true, the second if false. So those become our `if` and `else` assignments to `zoomFactor`.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/js-how-to-use-the-ternary-operator):

```
F.onmousewheel = function (e) {zoomFactor = e.wheelDelta > 0 ? 10 : 11;}
```

Into an `if` `else` block:

```
F.onmousewheel = function (e) {
    if(e.wheelDelta > 0) {
        zoomFactor = 10;
    }
    else {
        zoomFactor = 11;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear, but I am guessing this is what you are looking for:

```
F.onmousewheel = function(e) {
    if (e.wheelDelta > 0) {
        zoomFactor = 10;
    } else {
        zoomFactor = 11;
    }
};
```