# syntax in Javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax, conditional-operator, typeof

```
function togglePageElementVisibility(what)  
{  
    var obj = typeof what == 'object'  
    ? what : document.getElementById(what);  

    if (obj.style.display == 'none')  
        obj.style.display = 'block';  
    else  
        obj.style.display = 'none';  
    return false;  
}
```

I got this code from a website to hide and unhide part of a webpage. I've been trying to wrap my head around it but im not sure how to change the first part to an if and else statement instead of what it is. Can you help please?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw(VS.94).aspx

Comment: It is an 'if' (ternary conditional operator): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the ?: (ternary) operator in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-to-use-the-ternary-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example  Ternary Operator is used.

`condition` ? `if-true` : `if-false`

```
var obj;
if (typeof what === 'object') {
  obj = what;
} else {
  obj = document.getElementById(what);
}
```

is equal to

```
var obj = (typeof what === 'object') ? what : document.getElementById(what);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me!