# A way to combine multiple if statements all to one line with some clever spacing

Tags: javascript

I want to find a way to combine multiple if statements all to one line with some clever spacing.

```
var myBool = myObject.prop1 ||
    myObject.prop2 && 
    myObject.prop3.someproperty
```

Since prop3 might be empty so I want to check if "someproperty" exist in prop3.
But I do not want to add another if statement like 
`typeof myObject.prop3.someproperty === 'undefined` before my myBool.

Is there anyway that I can make everything in one line with clever spacing?

Comment: So do you mean `prop3` might be `undefined` or `prop3.someproperty` might be undefined. If the later, then your code as it is should be fine. `undefined` is falsy so that condition will evaluate as false anyway.

Comment: `.prop2 && (myObject.prop3 && myObject.prop3.someproperty)`

Comment: take in mind, that && comes before || so, so in your statement if prop1 is true the statement is true.

Comment: @JarlikStepsto Yes, that is what I want.

Comment: Related question: [How to use the ?: ternary operator in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-to-use-the-ternary-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myBool = myObject.prop1 ||
    myObject.prop2 && 
    myObject.prop3.someproperty != null
    ? myObject.prop3.someproperty
    : false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myBool = Boolean(myObject.prop1 ||
    myObject.prop2 && 
    myObject.prop3 && myObject.prop3.someproperty);
```

or

```
var myBool = !!(myObject.prop1 ||
    myObject.prop2 && 
    myObject.prop3 && myObject.prop3.someproperty);
```

since your naming implies that you expect myBool to contain a real boolean, not some truthy or falsy value