# OR operator to escape undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```
var x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('x')).length || 0;
```

Above code has an error. the || doesn't work in this case I wonder why. Actually I can do this with

```
var x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('x');
if(x.length){
    x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('x').lengt6h
}
```

but that's 4 lines of code. Is there any way to do it in one line?

Comment: what is the error that you are seeing?

Comment: what is undefined?

Comment: `var x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('x')||'[]').length`?

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage.getItem()` will return `null` if the key is not found, and parse may not like that. But an empty Array should be okay.

```
var x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('x') || '[]').length;
```

Using `JSON.parse` on a `null` value returns `null`. And calling `length` on `null` throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You need to ask if item `x` of localStorage isn't `null` before asking the length of it.

```js
var array = [{ 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 }, { 'four': 4, 'five': 5, 'six': 6 }];
localStorage.setItem('x', JSON.stringify(array));
if(localStorage.getItem('x') != null) var x = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('x'))).length;
```

Comment: if you check this way there's no need for the zero to be exist correct?

Comment: What value you expect for `x`?

Comment: the number of item in my array object.

Answer (score 0):

use ternary operator [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-to-use-the-ternary-operator-in-javascript)

```
 x=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('x')).length?JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('x')).length:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a shorthand if:

```
var x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('x')).length != 0 ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('x')).length : 0
```