# How to parse some data?

Tags: javascript, parsing, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm attempting to do some manipulations on array values that I have obtained from an API query within a React.js environment. However, these array values are numbers that are stored as `"strings"`, e.g., `"1.02011"`. I'm now attempting to take the inverse of this value as I wish to do some extra tricky stuff with it.

So, I have: `var usdgbp = parseFloat({this.state.quotes ? this.state.quotes.USDGBP : null});`

`{this.state.quotes ? this.state.quotes.USDGBP : null}` is something which is working fine elsewhere in the code...so, I'm thinking - what is the correct way of parsing the number out from a string of this nature/type, and within the React.js `class Module extends React.Component {}` setup.

Comment: Not sure about your question but `parseFloat(null)` == NaN so returning null in your else seems odd.  And your putting {} around the value?  why?

Comment: @Taplar It's a react.js prop when it is encolsed in {}.

Comment: Ok, well still parsing null seems odd.  You should probably return '0' maybe instead of null.

Comment: @Taplar so this is something I was just told off the bat. What exactly does `: null` mean in React.js? I was under the impression that it checks if it is *NOT* a null value. I'm using it to access the string value from the JSON data, which works fine.

Comment: This is not really a special "React.js" syntax - what you have is a [ternary operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript) inside `{}` which is not really valid JS.

Comment: `trueFalseCondition ? truthyResult : falseyResult`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function takes a string as argument, not an object (the `{}` syntax).

And you can parse your data in the component's `render` function:

```
class ExchangeRate extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    const { quotes } = this.state        

    if (!quotes) return null

    return (<span>Exchange rate: {parseFloat(quotes.USDGBP)}</span>)
  }
}
```