# In html and javascript, what would '?' be used for in this particular context?

Tags: javascript, html

```
x = (x === lightImages.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
```

I understand the rest of my code so I won't add it because that would be pointless. Basically I'm just unsure what the '? 0' does in this code, my friend coded it for me because I was struggling with the rest of the code and I'd like to know exactly what is does so I could use it again properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a ternary operator.

Basically if `(x === lightImages.length - 1)` is true `x = 0`, otherwise `x = x + 1`.

You can think of it as a compact `if () {} else {}` statement. What precedes `?` is the `if` condition, what comes immediately after is result. Anything after the `:` is the else result.

See here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator