# What is Question mark syntax in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function querySearch (query) {                 
    var results = query ? $scope.allContacts.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : [];                 
    return results;
}
```

What the question mark **`?`** does mean in here? Is it optional?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript

Comment: If `query` is `truthy` set `result` to the result of a filter using the query, otherwise set it to an empty array.

Comment: See [MDN JavaScript Reference - Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means: If evaluation of `query` is `truthy` (`typeof query != 'undefined' && query != null && query != 0 && query != false`), then return the result of evaluating `$scope.allContacts.filter(createFilterFor(query))` else return an empty array (`[]`).

In this case, it guarantees, that always an array is returned.

If the `query ?` is not performed and `query` is `null`, for instance, `$scope.allContacts.filter(createFilterFor(query))` could throw an exeption, so this is sometimes used for safety.