# Javascript's ternary operator semantic

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dive into the src code of jQuery, and at the very beginning of the the src code in the development version(3.2.1) of jQuery we find:

```
( function( global, factory ) {
"use strict";
if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
    module.exports = global.document ?
        factory( global, true ) :
        function( w ) {
            if ( !w.document ) {
                throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
            }
            return factory( w );
        };
} else {
    factory( global );
}
```

As far as my knowledge is concerned, I know that ternary operator comes after some condition, but here it comes after an assignment operator `module.exports = global.document ?`. Could you explain this? What it does in the context of the previous code?

Comment: ternary operator goes after anything really. If its not a boolean, it will be converted as such. So if global.document is null or undefined or "" or any other falsy value, it will be considered as false and if not, true

Comment: That means if global.document is true then module.exports is assigned global.document. If global.document is falsy then function( w ) is assigned to module.exports which is being exported

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ternary operator allow to conditionally evaluate two expressions (the first in case of the condition is true, the second one otherwise).

```
module.exports = global.document ?
        factory( global, true ) :
        function( w ) {
            if ( !w.document ) {
                throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
            }
            return factory( w );
        };
```

The assignment means that, the result of the conditional evaluation is assigned to `module.export`.

The ternary operator is a syntactic sugar and works like this:

```
function ternary_operator(condition, expression1, expression2) {
    if (condition) {
        return expression1;
    } else {
        return expression2;
    }
}
```

so you can translate the code to:

```
module.exports = ternary_operator(global.document,
        factory( global, true ),
        function( w ) {
            if ( !w.document ) {
                throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
            }
            return factory( w );
        });
```

Please, pay attention to:

```
factory( global, true )
```

and

```
    function( w ) {
        if ( !w.document ) {
            throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
        }
        return factory( w );
    };
```

They are both expressions: the result of the activation of the `factory` function is an expression; the definition of a function value is an expression too.

## Lazy evaluation

The function `ternary_operator` provides an *eager* ternary operator. The expressions are evaluated within the condition, and then one of them are returned. For example:

```
var l = ternary_operator(C, A, B);
1. evaluate C
2. evaluate A
3. evaluate B
4. activate function ternary_operator
5. assign to l the result of the function
```

Javascript ternary operator is lazy: that means that the condition is firstly evaluated, then just one of the other expression is evaluatued, gaining in terms of performance.

```
var l = C ? A : B;
1. evaluate C
2.1 if C is true evaluate A
2.2 if C is false evalutate B
3. assign to l the expression evaluated
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=b?c:d;
```

In this case the ternary operator does not check for *a=b* but rather for *b*. Thats because the assignment operator has a higher operator predescendence than the ternary operator, for a good reason.

```
(a=b)?c:d;
```

In this case the ternary operator really tests for *a=b*. In this case it will store b in a and return this value.