# What are these operators doing? String key = offset == -1 ? keyStroke : keyStroke.substring( offset + 1 );

Tags: java, operators

`String key = offset == -1 ? keyStroke :  keyStroke.substring( offset + 1 );`
I found an example of some code online and it contained this line that I do not understand.

This is a piece of code found in a [key binding example](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/). Specifically, "KeyboardAnimation.java" line 37.

This may come across as a dumb question, but I have no idea what is happening here. I could spend a long time doing research, but I feel like this could be fairly easily explained by someone (I can go into more detail about my reasoning, but it's beside the point).

I get that it's setting the variable `key` of type `String` to something. keyStroke is a String that is formatted the way a keystroke would be:

> Parses a string and returns a KeyStroke. The string must have the following >syntax:
>   * ( | )
>
> modifiers := shift | control | ctrl | meta | alt | altGraph
>
> typedID := typed
>
> typedKey := string of length 1 giving Unicode character.
>
> pressedReleasedID := (pressed | released) key
>
> key := KeyEvent key code name, i.e. the name following "VK_".
>
> If typed, pressed or released is not specified, pressed is assumed. Here are >some examples:
>
> ```
> "INSERT" => getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_INSERT, 0);
> "control DELETE" => getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK);
> "alt shift X" => getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, InputEvent.ALT_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK);
> "alt shift released X" => getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, InputEvent.ALT_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK, true);
> "typed a" => getKeyStroke('a');
> ```

(from: KeyStroke javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(String s))

Now, to get into what I actually don't know: Why does it appear to have a Boolean operator in there? What does the question mark do? What does the colon do?

I feel like this is stuff I should have learned before but haven't...

Comment: 1. The conditional operator `? :` (or ternary) and 2. A bitwise `or` on two `int` constants (which represent bitmasks).

Comment: A ternary operator is a shorthand of if else statement it like: if(String key = offset == -1){ keyStroke  } else { keyStroke.substring( offset + 1 ); }

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't really understand what either of you mean... As far as @Elliott's comment, what's a bitmask? A bitwise or on two int constants? And Fady, what would that kind of if statement do? I kind of get the picture, but I'm still a bit confused on the details... I've only been doing Java for a semester, so I apologize in advance for ignorant questions...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String key = offset == -1 ? keyStroke :  keyStroke.substring( offset + 1);
```

This is a variable declaration and initialization. It defines a variable:

```
String key
```

and initializes it immediately:

```
String key = ...;
```

Now, what it the value on the right side, that is used to initialize the string? It's a ternary statement, which is an expression of the form:

```
condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse
```

This expression thus has the value `valueIfTrue` if the boolean expression `condition` is true, and the value `valueIfFalse` if the boolean expression `condition` is false.

In your case, the key variable is thus initialized with the value of `keyStroke` if `offset == -1` is true, or with the value of `keyStroke.substring( offset + 1 )` if `offset == -1` is false.

The whole thing could be rewritten as

```
String key;
if (offset == -1) {
    key = keyStroke;
} 
else {
    key = keyStroke.substring(offset + 1);
}
```