# Best way to switch classes in Angular

Tags: angular

In my Angular4 application, I have a code to conditionally apply two classes that looks like this:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{ 'fa-toggle-on': category.active, 'fa-toggle-off': !category.active }">
</some-element>
```

This works, but is this really the recommended way? It feels a bit unclean to write down `category.active` twice. I was looking for something more if-else like, but could not find anything so far in the docs and on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: @Durga Not exactly a duplicate, because this is a Angular specific question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ngClass` directive takes an expression. The expression can evaluate to a string.

Here is how to [how to use the directive with the string](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass):

```
<some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>
```

So in your case use the expression that evaluates to a string:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="category.active ? 'fa-toggle-on' : 'fa-toggle-off'">
```