# Ternary "... ? ... : ..." operator throws an error

Tags: javascript, if-statement

May I ask why the following code returns an error?

### Error:

```
numberOne > numberTwo ? return "true" : return "false";
                        ^^^^^^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token return
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)``
```

### Code:

```js
function isGreaterThan(numberOne, numberTwo) {
    Numbering > numberTwo ? return "true" : return "false";
}
```

*Thank you for any help you can provide!*

Comment: The current answer has what you should use instead, but here’s more explanation: the conditional operator `… ? … : …` is (as the name suggests) an operator, so it operates on expressions and produces a value. A lot of expressions in JavaScript can have side-effects, like `i++` or `alert()`, but for the most part you’ll want to use the result of `?:`, as in `let higherNumber = a > b ? a : b;`. `return`, on the other hand, isn’t an expression at all – it’s its own statement. It doesn’t have a value, so you can’t use it in contexts like `?:` where an expression is expected.

Comment: Thank you @nicael for correcting my errors!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the ternary operator. And in fact you don't have to use it there at all, just

```
return numberOne>numberTwo;
```

If you are still wondering what's wrong with your ternary operator, here's how you would get it with ternary. It would do here the same trick but in more characters (i.e., no need to use it here but here's an example anyway)

```
return (numberOne > numberTwo ? true : false);
```

---

In case I have been unclear - **BOTH** of those return statements will do **EXACTLY** the same thing.

---

Expanding a bit on the topic - **why doesn't it work the way I'm using it**?

The ternary operator is supposed, itself, to return the result (not to be confused with the return of the function). It returns the result by evaluating either the first expression (after `?` and before `:`) or the second expression, which goes after `:`. In order for the ternary operator to return anything, both expressions must evaluate to anything. It doesn't make sense to put the `return` statement as one of the expressions inside the ternary operator as the `return` keyword doesn't evaluate to anything. I.e., writing the following is meaningless:

```
var lalala = return someVar;
```

and this is what the error is trying to tell you, it's the error of the same origin. I.e., it expected not `return`, but maybe `someVar + anotherVar`, `1 * 2`, `great > small` or anything else which can be evaluated.

**Recommended reading:** [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: @Death That's **exactly** what my code does. `numberOne>numberTwo` returns the BOOLEAN.

Comment: This solves the problem but doesn't address the question of why it is an error to use `return` in a ternary expression. The answer being that `return` is a statement not an expression (it doesn't evaluate to anything, EG. `console.log( return 'foo' );` is meaningless because `return 'foo'` doesn't evaluate to anything you could log), so it can't be used where an expression is required.

Comment: @Paulpro that's a fair note though, I'll add that

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a plain old `if` statement:

```
if(numberOne > numberTwo) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Cause an `if` statement branches *statements*. And `return` is a statement. A ternary however branches *expressions*, `true` and `false` are expressions, `return` isn’t. Therefore just move `return` in front of the ternary:

```
return numberOne > numberTwo ? true : false;
```

And that’s basically:

```
return numberOne > numberTwo;
```

Comment: As i said, i am trying to used this method instead, so that i can get a handle on all the methods

Answer (score 0):

So “?:” operator returns something it self so you shouldn’t write return your self do it like this
- function isGreaterThan(numberOne, numberTwo) {

return numberOne > numberTwo ? true : false;

}

Comment: Hey there @Aqua! Your answer could use some [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).