# d3-how to change colour of text based on value (if else)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dataset, based on the values i want to print "Warning: joe has watched 14 cat videos today" in either black or red. if value is bigger than 10 its in red.
How do i do this in using d3 or html formatting??

```
var dataset = [14, 5, 26, 23, 9];
d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .style('fill', 'darkOrange')
    .text(function(d, i){
        for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            result = "Warning: Joe watched " + d + " cat videos today";
        }
        return result;
    });
```

Need it to look like this

[image]

Comment: If watching 14 cat videos in a day justifies a warning then I need to re-evaluate my life choices :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out

Add style attribute to change color of text according to value of array

```
.style("color", function(d, i) {
      return d > 10 ? "#ff0000" : "#000";
    })
```

And add if else in .text(function(d, i){} to change text according to condition see in my answer

```js
var dataset = [14, 5, 26, 23, 9];
d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .style('fill', 'darkOrange')
    .style("color", function(d, i) {
      return d > 10 ? "#ff0000" : "#000";
    })
    .text(function(d, i){
        for (i=0; i<dataset.length; i++)
        {
            if(d > 10)
            {
              result = "Warning: Joe watched " + d + " cat videos today";
             }
             else
             {
              result = "Joe watched " + d + " cat videos today";
             }
        }
        return result;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, what does the part from the ? after mean?? And how come it does just change the values colour only??

Comment: @SavageBooBoo check my updated answer. I hope you get your answer

Comment: @SavageBooBoo, the ? is a ternary operator, it is a shorthand for an if else statement, see this [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6259982/7106086).