# Function explanation using the ?: ( conditional operator in javascript )

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I'm trying to understand this function that returns the ordinal numbers when we give it a number.

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how this is working with the conditional operator, could someone explain it to me?

```
function getOrdinalNum(n) {
  return n + (n > 0 ? ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][(n > 3 && n < 21) || n % 10 > 3 ? 0 : n % 10] : '');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to explain this sort of thing is to break it down into a function with `if` statements. Take a look at the `newFunction` it does the same thing that the function `getOrdinalNum` does:

```js
function getOrdinalNum(n) {
  return n + (n > 0 ? ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][(n > 3 && n < 21) || n % 10 > 3 ? 0 : n % 10] : '');
}

function newFunction(n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    if ((n > 3 && n < 21) || n % 10 > 3) {
      return n + 'th'; // essentially returning ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][0]; 
    } else {
      return n + ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][n % 10];
    }
  }
}

for(let i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  console.log(getOrdinalNum(i));
  console.log(newFunction(i));
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea too. However, for an even easier understanding, I'd propose breaking down these operations (`return n + ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][n % 10];`) into different variables like: `theIndexToChoose`, `theChoices`, `theFinalResult`

Answer (score 1):

Break it down like this:

```
n + 
(
 n > 0 
 ? ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd']
     [
       (n > 3 && n < 21) || n % 10 > 3 
       ? 0 
       : n % 10
     ] 
 : ''
);
```

Here:

1. JS checks if `n > 0`. If yes then:

   1. An array is created `['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd']`
   2. The next `[]` tells us a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) will follow
   3. Which property is determined by the ternary operation. Either `0` (which will mean (`th`) or the result of `n & 10`
   4. And the result of accessing that property is added whatever `n` was.
2. If `n` is smaller or equal with `0` then whatever `n` was, an empty string is added to it.

It helps to know the [operator precedence in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). Give it a goooood read and practice some.

Answer (score 0):

## Operators (unary, binary, ternary)

The *ternary* conditional operator is different than most other operators in that it takes 3 *operands* instead of one or two.

You are used to *unary* operators like the negative symbol in `-5` which takes one operand and makes it a negative value.

There is also the *binary* concatenation operator `+` used like `'hello ' + 'world'`. Here there are two operands which produce the value `'hello world'`.

The *ternary* conditional operator has the form

```
/* conditional expression */ ? /* expression if truthy */ : /* expression if not truthy*/
```

Where the comments are the *operands* for you to fill in with the more complex code from your example. `// if n > 0 then the complex expression, otherwise the empty string`

## Simple example.

Try to run the following statements in your browser.

```
console.log(true ? 'true value' : 'false value');

var x = 3 > 1 ? 'true value' : 'false value';
console.log(x);

prompt('try entering a blank space, or characters') ? 'a' : 'b';
```

The code flows much the same as the other answers describe. The first expression is emitted if the condition is truthy otherwise the second expression is emitted.

[Here are some docs on what I mean by truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)