# One liner that returns a value if evaluation is truthy and breaks if evaluation falsy?

Tags: javascript

Here is a piece of code I have in several places in my code:

```
req = this.getActiveRequestById(message.trans_id);
if (!req) {
    break;
}
```

How can I rewrite this as a one-liner?

**EDIT** I want to clarify that I need to store the return value in req for later use.

Comment: `if (!this.getActiveRequestById(message.trans_id)) break;`? What's the problem here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: *How can I rewrite this as a one-liner?* I would also question why here? why is this is a problem?

Comment: What are you `break`ing from?

Comment: @Bergi From a swtich case

Comment: @user1283776 And else you need to fall-through? If you are asking how to simplify your code and avoid duplicating parts, please post the whole code so that we can suggest an appropriate abstraction.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi: I'll try to keep your advise in mind for the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove var assignment and apply the condition directly to the value:

```js
if (!this.getActiveRequestById(message.trans_id)) break;
```

I would not suggest it but if you **need** to set a variable in a one liner if condition it should work:

```js
 if (!(req = this.getActiveRequestById(message.trans_id))) break;
```

**Notice that it generates confusion between comparison and assignment.**

Comment: you miss the part, expression vs statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!(reg = this.getActiveRequestById(message.trans_id))) break;
```