# Turn string to FALSE if it is equal to ''

Tags: javascript

The code I have returns a string:

```
return val ? val.name : "N/A";
```

But if the `val.name` returns "", it should return "N/A", not `val.name`. How to do that?

I tried

```
return val ? val.name === "" : "N/A";
return val.name ? val.name : "N/A";
etc.
```

But no luck yet.

Comment: How would you write this as an `if` statement? The [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is just shorthand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check whether `val.name` is truthy as well (an empty string is falsy), using the Boolean AND operator:

```
val && val.name ? val.name : "N/A"
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
const val = {
  name: ''
}

const a = val && val.name || "N/A";

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return (val || {}).name || 'N/A'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a safe-read method for a property on an `object`. You can create a method that receives an `object` and a `key` and safe read that property chaining the verifications. Examples of chaining you can use to approach this are:

```
obj && obj.key ? obj.key : "N/A"
```

or

```
(obj || {}).key || "N/A"
```

or

```
obj && obj.key || "N/A"
```

And in some future (I hope not so long) maybe you can use next one:

```
obj?.key || "N/A"
```

[Reference](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/here-are-three-upcoming-changes-to-javascript-that-youll-love-387bce1bfb0b)

Finally, a minimal example of a generic safe-read method could be:

```js
let obj1 = null;
let obj2 = {};
let obj3 = {name: ""}
let obj4 = {name: "John"}

const safeReadObj = (obj, key) => obj && obj[key] || "N/A";

// Test cases:
console.log(safeReadObj(obj1, "name"));
console.log(safeReadObj(obj2, "name"));
console.log(safeReadObj(obj3, "name"));
console.log(safeReadObj(obj4, "name"));
```

Comment: **Self-Note**: Do not elaborate the answer, just answer as fast as you can!

Comment: Yeah, quality answers are rare nowadays... +1 for the effort

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to get Idea what you can do...

```
function getModify(string) {
    return (string=="")?('N/A'):(string);
}
console.log(getww(""));
console.log(getww("ub"));

// Output
// N/A
// ub
```

Answer (score 0):

return val.name != "" ? val.name : "N/A";