# JavaScript.Closures and transfered arguments

Tags: javascript, closures

We have a function:

```
function f (a, b, c) {
function sum (a, b) {
return a + b;
}
}
```

Rewrite it as follows:

1. If arguments a and b not transfered, they're equals by default 2 and 3.
2. If argument c transfered and is a function, then it will run after the function sum called.
3. Function f must return the result of a function argument c,if it exist,or result of a function sum.

Comment: Oops! I thought you were just posting a homework question without any work done because you put your comments in the quote. Try to preview your post to make sure it's properly formatted before posting next time!

Comment: Formatting aside, it is extremely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry,for that.I just edited it.As it must be.

Comment: Yup.I knew that.Thank you a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I good understand your question this should be ok:

```js
function f (a = 2, b = 3, c) {
    function sum(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
    let s =  sum(a,b);
    return c instanceof Function ? c() : s;
}

console.log(f());
console.log(f(7,8));
console.log(f(9,10, ()=>11));
```

We use here [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260001/860099), [instanceof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof), and [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Sorry for a question.But what arguments in these two logs ? Is it  arrow function ?
console.log(f(7,8)); 
console.log(f(9,10, x=>11));

Comment: `x=>11` is arrow function (which always return 11). Change it to `()=>3`  and watch what happen. (I update answer and change it to ()=>11 because in function `f` in return... c() we not put any argument to x.

Comment: Oh,i think i got it.Thank you a lot ;)