# Getting: SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression

Tags: javascript

I am trying to resolve My issue can some one help me ? My code are

```
let addClass = (obj) => {obj.classList.add('active-input');}
let removeClass = (obj) => {obj.classList.remove('active-input');}
```

I am trying to create a form by using below HTML which is concatenating in a  variable and then I am updating it on DOM.

```
<input class="inputFull" list="ozip" id="orZip" name="OrZip" onfocus="addClass(this);this.placeholder=\'\';document.getElementById(\'orTitle\').style.display =\'block\';" onblur="this.value ? removeClass(this);document.getElementById(\'orTitle\').style.display =\'block\'; : document.getElementById(\'orTitle\').style.display =\'none\';this.placeholder=\'Origin postal code\'" placeholder="Origin postal code" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Can someone explain why I am getting **SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression**.

Comment: Getting this error onblur. Thanks for help

Comment: don't do this `onblur="this.value ? removeClass();document.getElementById(\'orTitle\').style.display =\'block\'; : document.getElementById(\'orTitle\').style.display =\'none\';this.placeholder=\'Origin postal code\'"` use a function and call it

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript You shuold swap a `;` for a `:`

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Reread the question and you'll see it is not what cause the error. Also, both answers make that clear.

Comment: @LGSon true. I've made a real quick look and found a `;` on the first part of the ternary operator and assumed that the error was just it - and if it wasn't, he could figure it out by himself. Anyway, [the link I've posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript) is a reference to create ternary operators - which is better than just fixing an expression in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>  this.value ? removeClass();
> ```

Here is the start of your ternary operator.

You have `this.value` as the condition.

Then you have `removeClass()` as the expression if it is true.

Then you end the statement.

The `:` and expression to return if `this.value` is falsy is missing.

---

I strongly suggest:

- Not using `on*` attributes at all
- Definitely not putting long strings of statements in them if you do (write a function)
- Not using ternary operations as general substitutes for `if` statements. They are designed for cases of `x = something ? a : b`.

Answer (score 2):

In your `onblur` handler, you've written:

```
onblur="this.value 
        ? 
        removeClass(this);
        document.getElementById(\'orTitle\').style.display =\'block\'; 
        : 
        document.getElementById(\'orTitle\').style.display =\'none\';
        this.placeholder=\'Origin postal code\'"
```

Given that there are two statements (with semicolon `;`) between the ternary conditional operator `? :` it is causing a syntax error.

I would suggest separately declaring the blur event handler in a JS file or a `<script>` element using `if.. else` blocks to mitigate the error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to reuse same function and modify the code as below - This will work as you expect:

```js
let toggleClass = (obj) => {
  if(obj.value) {
   obj.classList.remove('active-input')
   document.getElementById("orTitle").style.display = "block";
  } else {
   obj.classList.add('active-input');
   document.getElementById("orTitle").style.display = "none";
   obj.placeholder = "Origin postal code";
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="inputFull" list="ozip" id="orZip" name="OrZip" onfocus="toggleClass(this)" onblur="toggleClass(this)" placeholder="Origin postal code" autocomplete="off"/>
```