# Unknown Query Statement in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I read following statemend in JavaScript:

```
this.fade = (fade == undefined ? 5 : fade);
```

Its new for me therefore i don't know what does it mean.

Comment: Its called [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: By the way, simply `this.fade = fade || 5` would work, because `undefined` is falsy.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev `fade` looks like a number and it would assign 5 to `this.fade` if `fade` is 0 (which might not be desirable to OP)

Comment: @adiga Indeed :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its like a if statement.
You can translate it like:

```
if(fade == undefined ){
    this.fade = 5;
} else {
    this.fade = fade
}
```

Comment: _"Its like a if statement"_ No its not. You can execute statements inside `if` block but you can't use statements using ternary operator.

Comment: I think what OP meant was that the ternary operator is a short form of a simple if statement, which it is

Answer (score 0):

This is called the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

The ternary operator is a short form of a one-line if statement.

The expression before the `?` is the condition.
If it is true then the variable on the left side of the `=` is equal to the value before the `:`, otherwise, it is the value after the `:`.

The parentheses around this expression are completely optional.

```
this.fade = fade == undefined ? 5 : fade;
```

would have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It is the ternary operator. It means that if `fade == undefined` it will return `5` (`this.fade = 5`) else it will return `fade` (`this.fade = fade`).

To be more clear, is like writing an if-else statement:

```
if (fade == undefined) {
    this.fade = 5;
} else {
    this.fade = fade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have showed is using ternary operator. It is used to evaluate a final expression based on some condition. The general syntax of ternary operator is

```
condition ? exp1 : exp2;
```

`exp1,exp2` are two expression. If the condition is `true` the above whole line will evaluate to `exp1` otherwise `exp2`.

You can use `if else` for ternary operators. Like in your code it will be.

```
if(fade == undefined){
    this.fade = 5
}
else{
    this.fade = fade
}
```

**Note:**`if/else` can be always used instead of ternary operators but ternary operator can't be always used for `if` statements.

Comment: You can also change the first code block to this for better understanding `condition ? whentrue: whenfalse;`