# Converting Ternary Operator to if / else statements

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found a fix for my application, but I copied and pasted the code, which doesn't match with the rest of the code, I want to turn these ternary operators into if/else statements.

`const name = persona ? persona.player_name : steamID.getSteamID64();`

I tried to do:

```js
const name = persona;
if (name = persona) {
    persona.player_name;
} else {
    steamID.getSteamID64;
}
```

But it didn't work, any help will be appreciate it thanks!

Comment: Please read a javascript tutorial, i think that would be the most beneficial.

Comment: A helpful question may be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```js
let name = '';
if (persona) {
   name = persona.player_name;
} else {
   name = steamID.getSteamID64();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is, that the ternary operator doesn't check for equality in this example but for `undefined`, that means that you example will translate to the following:

```js
let name = undefined;
if (persona !== undefined) {
    name = persona.player_name;
} else {
    name = steamID.getSteamID64();
}
```

It would be written in human language like this: If persona is defined, assign property `player_name` to the variable named `name`. If persona is not defined, assign the result of `steamID.getSteamID64()` to `name`.

This is possible because just checking `if(foo)` is a shorthand for `if (foo !== undefined)`. And the ternary operator is an inline if-condition, so `if(foo)` can be translated to `foo ? then : else`.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `var` statement for declaring the value and assign later.

`const` needs a value and be careful by taking `name` as variable, becaus this is a short form  of the window's name `window.name`.

```
var name;

if (persona) name = persona.player_name;
else name = steamID.getSteamID64();
```