# Ternary Operator with Logical Operators

Tags: javascript, jsx, logical-operators, conditional-operator

I'm trying to use the logical operator && in my ternary operator while chaining and it isn't working...  For example:

```js
(x === 5 && y === 5) ? (do something) 
: (x === 5 && y === 4) ? (do something else) 
: (x === 5 && y === 3) ? (do a third thing) 
: null
```

Is this possible?  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working? Can you post your code and your expected output?

Comment: Yeah, seems to work fine?: https://jsfiddle.net/tf0ne36v/1/

Comment: what means *do something*? a statement or an expression? do you use the result of the ternary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: It's "working" on syntax, but ternary operators don't exist to enchase code inside

Answer (score 3):

```
x === 5 ? 
  y === 5 ? console.log('x=5, y=5') :
  y === 4 ? console.log('x=5, y=4') :
  y === 3 ? console.log('x=5, y=3') : null
: null
```

proof:

```js
const resp = (x,y) => x === 5 ? 
                        y === 5 ? 'x==5, y==5' :
                        y === 4 ? 'x==5, y==4' :
                        y === 3 ? 'x==5, y==3' : 'x==5, y==?'
                      : 'x==?, y==?'

console.log ( '1 ,2 ', resp(1,2) )  // 1 ,2  x==?, y==?
console.log ( '5 ,2 ', resp(5,2) )  // 5 ,2  x==5, y==? 
console.log ( '5 ,4 ', resp(5,4) )  // 5 ,4  x==5, y==4
```

Comment: not bad... (nice one)

Comment: it's hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

yes You can do your way :

```js
const Question = (x,y) => (x === 5 && y === 5) ?  'x==5, y==5' 
                        : (x === 5 && y === 4) ?  'x==5, y==4' 
                        : (x === 5 && y === 3) ?  'x==5, y==3' 
                        : 'x==?, y==?' 

console.log ( '1 ,2 ', Question(1,2) )  // 1 ,2  x==?, y==?
console.log ( '5 ,2 ', Question(5,2) )  // 5 ,2  x==?, y==? 
console.log ( '5 ,4 ', Question(5,4) )  // 5 ,4  x==5, y==4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses to specify nested conditions for success and failure.

```
    (x === 5 && y === 5) ? (do something) : ((x === 5 && y === 4) ? (do something
      else) : ((x === 5 && y === 3) ? (do a third thing) : null));
```

proof:

```js
const test = (x,y) => (x === 5 && y === 5) 
                      ? 'x==5, y==5' 
                      : ( (x === 5 && y === 4) 
                          ? 'x==5, y==4' 
                          : ( (x === 5 && y === 3) 
                              ? 'x==5, y==5'
                              : 'x==?, y==?'
                        )   );

console.log ( '1 ,2 ', test(1,2) )  // 1 ,2  x==?, y==?
console.log ( '5 ,2 ', test(5,2) )  // 5 ,2  x==?, y==? 
console.log ( '5 ,4 ', test(5,4) )  // 5 ,4  x==5, y==4
```