# How do I write a shorter arrow function using an if without curly braces around the body

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrow-functions

I want this but in fewer lines using arrows

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].every(
  value => {
    if (value > 0) {
      return 1
    }
  }))
```

> output: true

It is working fine but when I tried to reduce the lines as below code it is not working is there any way to do it, is it not possible to write a single if statement without using any ternary

```
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].every(value =>
  if (value > 0) 1)
);
```

```
output :  /tmp/main.js:1
console.log([1,2,3,4].every(value=> if(value>0) 1)) 
                                    ^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if'
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11

[Program exited with exit code 1]
```

Is it possible to return anything apart from true or false using arrow operator like this? I want to return awesome but it is throwing me an error.

```
k=val=>val>0 "awesome";
console.log(k(2))
k=val=>val>0 "awesome";
             ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

I tried to ask this question which is based on arrow function but someone told me to ask the question separately, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Just `value=> value>0`. You cannot use an  `if` because it's a statement, an arrow function without a body needs only an expression. Also, no real reason to return `1`

Comment: Just use a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript).

Comment: @DaneBrouwer why?

Comment: @VLAZ Ah, misread the question. Saw the OP returned `1` so I assumed they wanted to return some sort of value from the condition. Should literally just be able to provide the condition as you suggested.

Comment: @VLAZ thank you so much i got it value=> value>0 it will return true therefore every function directly take it as true suppose if i want return anything apart of 1 or 0 like  value=>if val>1 "awesome" in that case how can i do it ?? without using {} it is possible?

Comment: @IndratejReddy `value => value>1`

Comment: Check my answer. Happy coding 

Comment: what if i want to return any string it is possible when value>1 is it possible without using {} or ternary operator?

Comment: `console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].filter(value => value > 0));`

Comment: @IndratejReddy You have to use `ternary operator`. Anyway, i have updated my answer where without using `{}` to get the result you want.

Comment: Hi @IndratejReddy. Please check the answer and mark the question as answered if it so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].every(value => value > 0))
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].every(value => value > 0) ? "awesome" : null)
```

Comment: It's pointless to use a ternary operator in this case @RashedRahat

Comment: what if i want to return a string like "awesome" when value>0 without using any ternary operator or {}, is it possible to do that?

Comment: @IndratejReddy it is. The callback for every is (element, index, array). You could modify the array if you wanted to, but this is not what OP wanted.

Comment: @CyberEternal just want to try because of my curiosity :)

Comment: @SilviuBurcea is it possible to return anything apart from true or false using arrow operator like this i want to return awesome but it is throwing me an error

k=val=>val>0 "awesome";
console.log(k(2))
k=val=>val>0 "awesome";

Comment: @IndratejReddy, Actually, you can do it by the following way 
`console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].every(value => value > 0 ? 'any' : null))`, but in your case It's pointless

Comment: @IndratejReddy You have to use `ternary operator`. Anyway, i have updated my answer where without using `{}` to get the result you want.

Comment: @IndratejReddy you can do that, as pointed out by CyberEternal, but you need to do `reduce` instead of `every`