# (JavaScript) Why my if/else code didn't work?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-operator

I need to make a fibonacci sequence and I found this code below here. When I try to understand all code I saw "(i <= 1) ? i : arr[i-2] + arr[i-1]", I thought that was an simple if else shortcut condition, and I try to replace by the extended way just to be sure (see the last code). But now the code didn't work...

Stackoverflow code:

```js
function fib(n) {
  return new Array(n).fill(1).reduce((arr, _, i) => {
    arr.push((i <= 1) ? i : arr[i - 2] + arr[i - 1])
    return arr
  }, []);
}
console.log(fib(10))
```

My code with (extended if else):

```js
function fib(n) {
  return new Array(n).fill(1).reduce((arr, _, i) => {
    arr.push(
      if (i <= 1) {
        i
      } else {
        arr[i - 2] + arr[i - 1]
      })
    return arr
  }, []);
}
console.log(fib(10))
```

Why my code is not equivalent to the code above?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator. You can't just drop an `if` in `.push()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: “*I thought that was an simple if else shortcut condition*” While this is kind of close to true, any old `if`/`else` is not a drop-in replacement for something that was originally written using the ternary operator `?`

Comment: Your code doesn’t work because it’s syntactically incorrect — simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what [@esqew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269970/esqew) said.

> *“I thought that was an simple if else shortcut condition”* While this
> is kind of close to true, any old `if`/`else` is not a drop-in
> replacement for something that was originally written using the
> ternary operator `?`

Replacing a [`Conditional Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) with an `if statement` directly will throw an error.

If you want to use `if`/`else` syntax inside a function parameter you could  write the code as a function in the form of an [`IIFE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```js
(() => {
  if (i <= 1) {
    return i;
  } else {
    return arr[i - 2] + arr[i - 1];
  }
})();
```

**Demo:**

```js
function fib(n) {
  return new Array(n).fill(1).reduce((arr, _, i) => {
    arr.push(
      (() => {
        if (i <= 1) {
          return i;
        } else {
          return arr[i - 2] + arr[i - 1];
        }
      })()
    );
    return arr;
  }, []);
}

console.log(fib(10));
```

Comment: Thanks!! now I understand.