# How to interpret this conditional branching in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
this.orientation = this.props.orientation
  ? this.props.orientation == 'horizontal'
    ? 'row'
    : 'column'
  : 'column';
```

May I know how I interpret this conditional branching? Got this code somewhere else from the web. I did read this https://javascript.info/ifelse#multiple but I still can't understand it.

From my understanding is that this.props.orientation which the orientation is retrieved from the parent. If this.props.orietation == 'horizontal' then return column? Then else if this.props.orientation =='row' then return column?

Comment: It is not really "conditional branching" but  a  Conditional Operator "ternary"; but I digress..

Comment: Oh, thanks for the information given! Glad to clarify my error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting parentheses will make things clearer.

```
this.orientation = this.props.orientation ?
(this.props.orientation == 'horizontal' ? 'row' : 'column') :
'column';
```

If `this.props.orientation` is not null or empty, it returns either `'row'` or `'column'` based on its value compared to "horizontal" (`'row'` if `true`, `'column'` otherwise). If it is null or empty, it returns `'column'` as a default.